# Transliteration of sanskrit or devanagari texts using polyglossia or other packages

Tags: polyglossia

I wanted to know if there is a way to transliterate devanagari texts within LaTeX itself. I have been using the wonderful `polyglossia` package, and I am able to enter Unicode devanagari texts into LaTeX and compile them. No problems. However, I was wondering if there is a way for LaTeX to convert Unicode devanagari fonts into romanized transliteration? The rules for devanagari transliteration are pretty well standardized, but I have not seen a package that does the transliteration in LaTeX--so that I don't have to keep making adjustments to both the devanagari and the transliteration each time.

If anyone has any suggestions about doing this in LaTeX, or even best practices outside of LaTeX, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 11):

You can use xetex input mapping feature. It is used to typeset [transliterated devanagari](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/generic/devanagari). Other example is [RomDev](https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev), for input in unicode transliteration. I haven't find any map file for conversion in the opposite direction, but it was not difficult to modify the [RomDev map](https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev/blob/master/RomDev.map) to go in the other way.

Download the file [DevRom.map](https://gist.github.com/1575793) and compile it with

```
teckit_compile DevRom.map
```

Copy the resulting file `DevRom.tec` somewhere xetex can find it and run `texhash`.

Usage sample:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english} 
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit} 
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{nakula.ttf}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Script=Roman,Mapping=DevRom]{Gentium}
\begin{document}
\def\devanagarisample{%
उदु ज्योतिरमृतं विश्वजन्यं विश्वानरः सविता देवो अश्रेत् ।
क्रत्वा देवानामजनिष्ट चक्षुराविरकर्भुवनं विश्वमुषाः ॥ १ ॥
प्र मे पन्था देवयाना अदृश्रन्नमर्धन्तो वसुभिरिष्कृतासः ।
अभूदु केतुरुषसः पुरस्तात्प्रतीच्यागादधि हर्म्येभ्यः ॥ २ ॥ 
}
%\devscript
\noindent\textsanskrit\devanagarisample

\devtransl
\noindent\devanagarisample
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Sample of devangari and transliteration from one source]

Important lines are

```
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{nakula.ttf}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Script=Roman,Mapping=DevRom]{Gentium}
```

where we define font command for print devanagari using `polyglossia` and command for printing of the transliteration.

If you want output using another transliteration method, you can easily adjust map method yourself there are lines in the form

```
U+093D <> U+0027 ;unstyled apostrophe
```

where is the input code, then output code and comment after the semicolon. Just swap input and output code.

Comment: Oh excellent. Thanks so much. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @krishnab I have added a mapping file to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502515/reversing-text-mapping-devanagari-to-iast-transliteration?noredirect=1&lq=1 based on the IAST scheme. Perhaps it may be of some use.

Answer (score 6):

Yes we do have a package in which transliteration is automatically done.

[image: screenshot]

Try the [skt](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/sanskrit) package.

Comment: To make it visually pretty and scroll easily can you crop the `.png` and update your post. Thanks

Comment: @texenthusiast its not a .png its a .pdf, and I don't know to crop. In case you are familiar with go ahead and edit it. Regards,

Comment: `pdfcrop fileName.pdf` at the command line terminal generates cropped pdf `fileName-crop.pdf`. Other approach might be to use [`standalone`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) class instead of `article` class. It generates cropped pdf automatically generally used for `Tikz Pictures`.

Comment: Just make a screenshot.