# Reversing Text Mapping (Devanagari to IAST Transliteration)

Tags: xetex, mapping, transliteration

I am interested in writing Devanagari text in LaTeX file, to transliterate into, and make it appear in, IAST scheme.
e.g.
I want to write

`\iast{रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे}`

and it should appear like

`rāmo rājamaṇi sadā vijayate rāmaṃ rameśaṃ bhaje`.

A valid solution is presented in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40181/transliteration-of-sanskrit-or-devanagari-texts-using-polyglossia-or-other-packa), but the provided DevRom map does not produce standard IAST transliteration.

e.g. 
`रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे` should go to
`rāmo rājamaṇi sadā vijayate rāmaṃ rameśaṃ bhaje`.

But instead it goes to `RāMo RāJMṆi SDā ViJYte RāMṃ RMeŚṃ BhJe/` (which transliterates back to `रामो राज्म्णि स्दा विज्य्ते राम्ं र्मेश्ं भ्जे/`, clearly incorrect).

As I understand, IAST to Devanagari is one-to-one mapping. I also found this [iast.map](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/generic/devanagari/iast.map), which can transliterate from IAST to Devanagari. What I am trying to do is obtain the reverse of this mapping, for Devanagari to IAST. While the original answer mentions it to be as simple as swapping the input and output alphabet, there are certain lines in the `iast.map` that I don't understand (and don't think are reversible).

Thus, could someone either tell me how to reverse the mapping properly, or provide a reversed mapping, or provide a mapping for Devanagari-to-IAST that is reversible?

Thank you.

---

**Solution**

I've put together the file provided in the answer and stripped off unnecessary components. Sample LaTeX file and map file can be found at the gist: https://gist.github.com/hrishikeshrt/c35e1a5332a4fbcdcdf7102446d2e796

---

Comment: I will look at iast.map. Some examples of mapping: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175579/complex-ligatures-in-devan%c4%81gar%c4%ab/511128?noredirect=1#comment1292663_511128 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397080/how-to-typeset-ancient-persian-scripts-in-latex/505924#505924 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346630/what-is-mapping-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-my-advantage/507452#507452

Comment: Please be aware that fontname control sequences are *switches* so with `\skt{}` the braces do nothing (they do not harm either). If your document is mainly in the main font, you can use `setmainfont{Sanskrit2003}`. Deva may be used for command names - this may save switching keyboards many times.  MWE: ```\documentclass[12pt]{article}\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit2003}\newfontfamily\ट{Sanskrit2003}[Mapping=deva-to-iast]
\begin{document}
रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे।

{\ट रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे।}
\end{document}```

Comment: Note also: Sanskrit2003 font does not have the `dev2` font feature. This may or may not have an effect, depending on the shaping engine used by your font renderer.

Comment: Good point about the control sequences. I'm defining commands as `\newfontfamily\textskt{Sanskrit2003}`
`\newfontfamily\textiast[Mapping=deva-to-iast]{Sanskrit2003}`

`\newcommand{\skt}[1]{{\textskt{#1}}}`
and `\newcommand{\iast}[1]{{\textiast{#1}}}` to get around that and make `\iast{}` work as expected.

Comment: Good technique. That is how the latex text commands are also defined, from what it appears: such that `\textit{}` is somewhat like `\newcommand\textit[1]{{\itshape{#1}}}`. The font switch is then restricted to a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 2 of the map file: (30k char limit per answer box):

```
U+0915U+094C<>U+006BU+0061U+0075;कौ kau
U+0916U+094C<>U+006BU+0068U+0061U+0075;खौ khau
U+0917U+094C<>U+0067U+0061U+0075;गौ gau
U+0918U+094C<>U+0067U+0068U+0061U+0075;घौ ghau
U+0919U+094C<>U+1E45U+0061U+0075;ङौ ṅau
U+091AU+094C<>U+0063U+0061U+0075;चौ cau
U+091BU+094C<>U+0063U+0068U+0061U+0075;छौ chau
U+091CU+094C<>U+006AU+0061U+0075;जौ jau
U+091DU+094C<>U+006AU+0068U+0061U+0075;झौ jhau
U+091EU+094C<>U+00F1U+0061U+0075;ञौ ñau
U+091FU+094C<>U+1E6DU+0061U+0075;टौ ṭau
U+0920U+094C<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0061U+0075;ठौ ṭhau
U+0921U+094C<>U+1E0DU+0061U+0075;डौ ḍau
U+0922U+094C<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0061U+0075;ढौ ḍhau
U+0923U+094C<>U+1E47U+0061U+0075;णौ ṇau
U+0924U+094C<>U+0074U+0061U+0075;तौ tau
U+0925U+094C<>U+0074U+0068U+0061U+0075;थौ thau
U+0926U+094C<>U+0064U+0061U+0075;दौ dau
U+0927U+094C<>U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0075;धौ dhau
U+0928U+094C<>U+006EU+0061U+0075;नौ nau
U+092AU+094C<>U+0070U+0061U+0075;पौ pau
U+092BU+094C<>U+0070U+0068U+0061U+0075;फौ phau
U+092CU+094C<>U+0062U+0061U+0075;बौ bau
U+092DU+094C<>U+0062U+0068U+0061U+0075;भौ bhau
U+092EU+094C<>U+006DU+0061U+0075;मौ mau
U+092FU+094C<>U+0079U+0061U+0075;यौ yau
U+0930U+094C<>U+0072U+0061U+0075;रौ rau
U+0932U+094C<>U+006CU+0061U+0075;लौ lau
U+0935U+094C<>U+0076U+0061U+0075;वौ vau
U+0936U+094C<>U+015BU+0061U+0075;शौ śau
U+0937U+094C<>U+1E63U+0061U+0075;षौ ṣau
U+0938U+094C<>U+0073U+0061U+0075;सौ sau
U+0939U+094C<>U+0068U+0061U+0075;हौ hau
U+0958U+094C<>U+0071U+0061U+0075;क़ौ qau
U+0959U+094C<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061U+0075;ख़ौ k͟hau
U+095AU+094C<>U+0121U+0061U+0075;ग़ौ ġau
U+095BU+094C<>U+007AU+0061U+0075;ज़ौ zau
U+095CU+094C<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0075;ड़ौ dddhau
U+095DU+094C<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061U+0075;ढ़ौ ṛhau
U+095EU+094C<>U+0066U+0061U+0075;फ़ौ fau
U+095FU+094C<>U+0079U+0079U+0061U+0075;य़ौ yyau
U+0929U+094C<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0061U+0075;ऩौ nnnau
U+0931U+094C<>U+0072U+0072U+0061U+0075;ऱौ rrau

U+0933U+094C<>U+1E37U+0061U+0075;ळौ ḷau
U+0934U+094C<>U+1E3BU+0061U+0075;ऴौ ḻau
U+0915U+094F<>U+006BU+0061U+0077;कॏ kaw
U+0916U+094F<>U+006BU+0068U+0061U+0077;खॏ khaw
U+0917U+094F<>U+0067U+0061U+0077;गॏ gaw
U+0918U+094F<>U+0067U+0068U+0061U+0077;घॏ ghaw
U+0919U+094F<>U+1E45U+0061U+0077;ङॏ ṅaw
U+091AU+094F<>U+0063U+0061U+0077;चॏ caw
U+091BU+094F<>U+0063U+0068U+0061U+0077;छॏ chaw
U+091CU+094F<>U+006AU+0061U+0077;जॏ jaw
U+091DU+094F<>U+006AU+0068U+0061U+0077;झॏ jhaw
U+091EU+094F<>U+00F1U+0061U+0077;ञॏ ñaw
U+091FU+094F<>U+1E6DU+0061U+0077;टॏ ṭaw
U+0920U+094F<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0061U+0077;ठॏ ṭhaw
U+0921U+094F<>U+1E0DU+0061U+0077;डॏ ḍaw
U+0922U+094F<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0061U+0077;ढॏ ḍhaw
U+0923U+094F<>U+1E47U+0061U+0077;णॏ ṇaw
U+0924U+094F<>U+0074U+0061U+0077;तॏ taw
U+0925U+094F<>U+0074U+0068U+0061U+0077;थॏ thaw
U+0926U+094F<>U+0064U+0061U+0077;दॏ daw
U+0927U+094F<>U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0077;धॏ dhaw
U+0928U+094F<>U+006EU+0061U+0077;नॏ naw
U+092AU+094F<>U+0070U+0061U+0077;पॏ paw
U+092BU+094F<>U+0070U+0068U+0061U+0077;फॏ phaw
U+092CU+094F<>U+0062U+0061U+0077;बॏ baw
U+092DU+094F<>U+0062U+0068U+0061U+0077;भॏ bhaw
U+092EU+094F<>U+006DU+0061U+0077;मॏ maw
U+092FU+094F<>U+0079U+0061U+0077;यॏ yaw
U+0930U+094F<>U+0072U+0061U+0077;रॏ raw
U+0932U+094F<>U+006CU+0061U+0077;लॏ law
U+0935U+094F<>U+0076U+0061U+0077;वॏ vaw
U+0936U+094F<>U+015BU+0061U+0077;शॏ śaw
U+0937U+094F<>U+1E63U+0061U+0077;षॏ ṣaw
U+0938U+094F<>U+0073U+0061U+0077;सॏ saw
U+0939U+094F<>U+0068U+0061U+0077;हॏ haw
U+0958U+094F<>U+0071U+0061U+0077;क़ॏ qaw
U+0959U+094F<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061U+0077;ख़ॏ k͟haw
U+095AU+094F<>U+0121U+0061U+0077;ग़ॏ ġaw
U+095BU+094F<>U+007AU+0061U+0077;ज़ॏ zaw
U+095CU+094F<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0077;ड़ॏ dddhaw
U+095DU+094F<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061U+0077;ढ़ॏ ṛhaw
U+095EU+094F<>U+0066U+0061U+0077;फ़ॏ faw
U+095FU+094F<>U+0079U+0079U+0061U+0077;य़ॏ yyaw
U+0929U+094F<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0061U+0077;ऩॏ nnnaw
U+0931U+094F<>U+0072U+0072U+0061U+0077;ऱॏ rraw
U+0933U+094F<>U+1E37U+0061U+0077;ळॏ ḷaw
U+0934U+094F<>U+1E3BU+0061U+0077;ऴॏ ḻaw
U+0915U+0956<>U+006BU+0075U+0065;कॖ kue
U+0916U+0956<>U+006BU+0068U+0075U+0065;खॖ khue
U+0917U+0956<>U+0067U+0075U+0065;गॖ gue
U+0918U+0956<>U+0067U+0068U+0075U+0065;घॖ ghue
U+0919U+0956<>U+1E45U+0075U+0065;ङॖ ṅue
U+091AU+0956<>U+0063U+0075U+0065;चॖ cue
U+091BU+0956<>U+0063U+0068U+0075U+0065;छॖ chue
U+091CU+0956<>U+006AU+0075U+0065;जॖ jue
U+091DU+0956<>U+006AU+0068U+0075U+0065;झॖ jhue
U+091EU+0956<>U+00F1U+0075U+0065;ञॖ ñue
U+091FU+0956<>U+1E6DU+0075U+0065;टॖ ṭue
U+0920U+0956<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0075U+0065;ठॖ ṭhue
U+0921U+0956<>U+1E0DU+0075U+0065;डॖ ḍue
U+0922U+0956<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0075U+0065;ढॖ ḍhue
U+0923U+0956<>U+1E47U+0075U+0065;णॖ ṇue
U+0924U+0956<>U+0074U+0075U+0065;तॖ tue
U+0925U+0956<>U+0074U+0068U+0075U+0065;थॖ thue
U+0926U+0956<>U+0064U+0075U+0065;दॖ due
U+0927U+0956<>U+0064U+0068U+0075U+0065;धॖ dhue
U+0928U+0956<>U+006EU+0075U+0065;नॖ nue
U+092AU+0956<>U+0070U+0075U+0065;पॖ pue
U+092BU+0956<>U+0070U+0068U+0075U+0065;फॖ phue
U+092CU+0956<>U+0062U+0075U+0065;बॖ bue
U+092DU+0956<>U+0062U+0068U+0075U+0065;भॖ bhue
U+092EU+0956<>U+006DU+0075U+0065;मॖ mue
U+092FU+0956<>U+0079U+0075U+0065;यॖ yue
U+0930U+0956<>U+0072U+0075U+0065;रॖ rue
U+0932U+0956<>U+006CU+0075U+0065;लॖ lue
U+0935U+0956<>U+0076U+0075U+0065;वॖ vue
U+0936U+0956<>U+015BU+0075U+0065;शॖ śue
U+0937U+0956<>U+1E63U+0075U+0065;षॖ ṣue
U+0938U+0956<>U+0073U+0075U+0065;सॖ sue
U+0939U+0956<>U+0068U+0075U+0065;हॖ hue
U+0958U+0956<>U+0071U+0075U+0065;क़ॖ que
U+0959U+0956<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0075U+0065;ख़ॖ k͟hue
U+095AU+0956<>U+0121U+0075U+0065;ग़ॖ ġue
U+095BU+0956<>U+007AU+0075U+0065;ज़ॖ zue
U+095CU+0956<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0075U+0065;ड़ॖ dddhue
U+095DU+0956<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0075U+0065;ढ़ॖ ṛhue
U+095EU+0956<>U+0066U+0075U+0065;फ़ॖ fue
U+095FU+0956<>U+0079U+0079U+0075U+0065;य़ॖ yyue
U+0929U+0956<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0075U+0065;ऩॖ nnnue
U+0931U+0956<>U+0072U+0072U+0075U+0065;ऱॖ rrue
U+0933U+0956<>U+1E37U+0075U+0065;ळॖ ḷue
U+0934U+0956<>U+1E3BU+0075U+0065;ऴॖ ḻue
U+0915U+0957<>U+006BU+016BU+0065;कॗ kūe
U+0916U+0957<>U+006BU+0068U+016BU+0065;खॗ khūe
U+0917U+0957<>U+0067U+016BU+0065;गॗ gūe
U+0918U+0957<>U+0067U+0068U+016BU+0065;घॗ ghūe
U+0919U+0957<>U+1E45U+016BU+0065;ङॗ ṅūe
U+091AU+0957<>U+0063U+016BU+0065;चॗ cūe
U+091BU+0957<>U+0063U+0068U+016BU+0065;छॗ chūe
U+091CU+0957<>U+006AU+016BU+0065;जॗ jūe
U+091DU+0957<>U+006AU+0068U+016BU+0065;झॗ jhūe
U+091EU+0957<>U+00F1U+016BU+0065;ञॗ ñūe
U+091FU+0957<>U+1E6DU+016BU+0065;टॗ ṭūe
U+0920U+0957<>U+1E6DU+0068U+016BU+0065;ठॗ ṭhūe
U+0921U+0957<>U+1E0DU+016BU+0065;डॗ ḍūe
U+0922U+0957<>U+1E0DU+0068U+016BU+0065;ढॗ ḍhūe
U+0923U+0957<>U+1E47U+016BU+0065;णॗ ṇūe
U+0924U+0957<>U+0074U+016BU+0065;तॗ tūe
U+0925U+0957<>U+0074U+0068U+016BU+0065;थॗ thūe
U+0926U+0957<>U+0064U+016BU+0065;दॗ dūe
U+0927U+0957<>U+0064U+0068U+016BU+0065;धॗ dhūe
U+0928U+0957<>U+006EU+016BU+0065;नॗ nūe
U+092AU+0957<>U+0070U+016BU+0065;पॗ pūe
U+092BU+0957<>U+0070U+0068U+016BU+0065;फॗ phūe
U+092CU+0957<>U+0062U+016BU+0065;बॗ būe
U+092DU+0957<>U+0062U+0068U+016BU+0065;भॗ bhūe
U+092EU+0957<>U+006DU+016BU+0065;मॗ mūe
U+092FU+0957<>U+0079U+016BU+0065;यॗ yūe
U+0930U+0957<>U+0072U+016BU+0065;रॗ rūe
U+0932U+0957<>U+006CU+016BU+0065;लॗ lūe
U+0935U+0957<>U+0076U+016BU+0065;वॗ vūe
U+0936U+0957<>U+015BU+016BU+0065;शॗ śūe
U+0937U+0957<>U+1E63U+016BU+0065;षॗ ṣūe
U+0938U+0957<>U+0073U+016BU+0065;सॗ sūe
U+0939U+0957<>U+0068U+016BU+0065;हॗ hūe
U+0958U+0957<>U+0071U+016BU+0065;क़ॗ qūe
U+0959U+0957<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+016BU+0065;ख़ॗ k͟hūe
U+095AU+0957<>U+0121U+016BU+0065;ग़ॗ ġūe
U+095BU+0957<>U+007AU+016BU+0065;ज़ॗ zūe
U+095CU+0957<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+016BU+0065;ड़ॗ dddhūe
U+095DU+0957<>U+1E5BU+0068U+016BU+0065;ढ़ॗ ṛhūe
U+095EU+0957<>U+0066U+016BU+0065;फ़ॗ fūe
U+095FU+0957<>U+0079U+0079U+016BU+0065;य़ॗ yyūe
U+0929U+0957<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+016BU+0065;ऩॗ nnnūe
U+0931U+0957<>U+0072U+0072U+016BU+0065;ऱॗ rrūe
U+0933U+0957<>U+1E37U+016BU+0065;ळॗ ḷūe
U+0934U+0957<>U+1E3BU+016BU+0065;ऴॗ ḻūe
U+0915U+0962<>U+006BU+1E37;कॢ kḷ
U+0916U+0962<>U+006BU+0068U+1E37;खॢ khḷ
U+0917U+0962<>U+0067U+1E37;गॢ gḷ
U+0918U+0962<>U+0067U+0068U+1E37;घॢ ghḷ
U+0919U+0962<>U+1E45U+1E37;ङॢ ṅḷ
U+091AU+0962<>U+0063U+1E37;चॢ cḷ
U+091BU+0962<>U+0063U+0068U+1E37;छॢ chḷ
U+091CU+0962<>U+006AU+1E37;जॢ jḷ
U+091DU+0962<>U+006AU+0068U+1E37;झॢ jhḷ
U+091EU+0962<>U+00F1U+1E37;ञॢ ñḷ
U+091FU+0962<>U+1E6DU+1E37;टॢ ṭḷ
U+0920U+0962<>U+1E6DU+0068U+1E37;ठॢ ṭhḷ
U+0921U+0962<>U+1E0DU+1E37;डॢ ḍḷ
U+0922U+0962<>U+1E0DU+0068U+1E37;ढॢ ḍhḷ
U+0923U+0962<>U+1E47U+1E37;णॢ ṇḷ
U+0924U+0962<>U+0074U+1E37;तॢ tḷ
U+0925U+0962<>U+0074U+0068U+1E37;थॢ thḷ
U+0926U+0962<>U+0064U+1E37;दॢ dḷ
U+0927U+0962<>U+0064U+0068U+1E37;धॢ dhḷ
U+0928U+0962<>U+006EU+1E37;नॢ nḷ
U+092AU+0962<>U+0070U+1E37;पॢ pḷ
U+092BU+0962<>U+0070U+0068U+1E37;फॢ phḷ
U+092CU+0962<>U+0062U+1E37;बॢ bḷ
U+092DU+0962<>U+0062U+0068U+1E37;भॢ bhḷ
U+092EU+0962<>U+006DU+1E37;मॢ mḷ
U+092FU+0962<>U+0079U+1E37;यॢ yḷ
U+0930U+0962<>U+0072U+1E37;रॢ rḷ
U+0932U+0962<>U+006CU+1E37;लॢ lḷ
U+0935U+0962<>U+0076U+1E37;वॢ vḷ
U+0936U+0962<>U+015BU+1E37;शॢ śḷ
U+0937U+0962<>U+1E63U+1E37;षॢ ṣḷ
U+0938U+0962<>U+0073U+1E37;सॢ sḷ
U+0939U+0962<>U+0068U+1E37;हॢ hḷ
U+0958U+0962<>U+0071U+1E37;क़ॢ qḷ
U+0959U+0962<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E37;ख़ॢ k͟hḷ
U+095AU+0962<>U+0121U+1E37;ग़ॢ ġḷ
U+095BU+0962<>U+007AU+1E37;ज़ॢ zḷ
U+095CU+0962<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E37;ड़ॢ dddhḷ
U+095DU+0962<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E37;ढ़ॢ ṛhḷ
U+095EU+0962<>U+0066U+1E37;फ़ॢ fḷ
U+095FU+0962<>U+0079U+0079U+1E37;य़ॢ yyḷ
U+0929U+0962<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+1E37;ऩॢ nnnḷ
U+0931U+0962<>U+0072U+0072U+1E37;ऱॢ rrḷ
U+0933U+0962<>U+1E37U+1E37;ळॢ ḷḷ
U+0934U+0962<>U+1E3BU+1E37;ऴॢ ḻḷ
U+0915U+0963<>U+006BU+1E39;कॣ kḹ
U+0916U+0963<>U+006BU+0068U+1E39;खॣ khḹ
U+0917U+0963<>U+0067U+1E39;गॣ gḹ
U+0918U+0963<>U+0067U+0068U+1E39;घॣ ghḹ
U+0919U+0963<>U+1E45U+1E39;ङॣ ṅḹ
U+091AU+0963<>U+0063U+1E39;चॣ cḹ
U+091BU+0963<>U+0063U+0068U+1E39;छॣ chḹ
U+091CU+0963<>U+006AU+1E39;जॣ jḹ
U+091DU+0963<>U+006AU+0068U+1E39;झॣ jhḹ
U+091EU+0963<>U+00F1U+1E39;ञॣ ñḹ
U+091FU+0963<>U+1E6DU+1E39;टॣ ṭḹ
U+0920U+0963<>U+1E6DU+0068U+1E39;ठॣ ṭhḹ
U+0921U+0963<>U+1E0DU+1E39;डॣ ḍḹ
U+0922U+0963<>U+1E0DU+0068U+1E39;ढॣ ḍhḹ
U+0923U+0963<>U+1E47U+1E39;णॣ ṇḹ
U+0924U+0963<>U+0074U+1E39;तॣ tḹ
U+0925U+0963<>U+0074U+0068U+1E39;थॣ thḹ
U+0926U+0963<>U+0064U+1E39;दॣ dḹ
U+0927U+0963<>U+0064U+0068U+1E39;धॣ dhḹ
U+0928U+0963<>U+006EU+1E39;नॣ nḹ
U+092AU+0963<>U+0070U+1E39;पॣ pḹ
U+092BU+0963<>U+0070U+0068U+1E39;फॣ phḹ
U+092CU+0963<>U+0062U+1E39;बॣ bḹ
U+092DU+0963<>U+0062U+0068U+1E39;भॣ bhḹ
U+092EU+0963<>U+006DU+1E39;मॣ mḹ
U+092FU+0963<>U+0079U+1E39;यॣ yḹ
U+0930U+0963<>U+0072U+1E39;रॣ rḹ
U+0932U+0963<>U+006CU+1E39;लॣ lḹ
U+0935U+0963<>U+0076U+1E39;वॣ vḹ
U+0936U+0963<>U+015BU+1E39;शॣ śḹ
U+0937U+0963<>U+1E63U+1E39;षॣ ṣḹ
U+0938U+0963<>U+0073U+1E39;सॣ sḹ
U+0939U+0963<>U+0068U+1E39;हॣ hḹ
U+0958U+0963<>U+0071U+1E39;क़ॣ qḹ
U+0959U+0963<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E39;ख़ॣ k͟hḹ
U+095AU+0963<>U+0121U+1E39;ग़ॣ ġḹ
U+095BU+0963<>U+007AU+1E39;ज़ॣ zḹ
U+095CU+0963<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E39;ड़ॣ dddhḹ
U+095DU+0963<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E39;ढ़ॣ ṛhḹ
U+095EU+0963<>U+0066U+1E39;फ़ॣ fḹ
U+095FU+0963<>U+0079U+0079U+1E39;य़ॣ yyḹ
U+0929U+0963<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+1E39;ऩॣ nnnḹ
U+0931U+0963<>U+0072U+0072U+1E39;ऱॣ rrḹ
U+0933U+0963<>U+1E37U+1E39;ळॣ ḷḹ
U+0934U+0963<>U+1E3BU+1E39;ऴॣ ḻḹ
U+0915U+0949<>U+006BU+006FU+0302;कॉ kô
U+0916U+0949<>U+006BU+0068U+006FU+0302;खॉ khô
U+0917U+0949<>U+0067U+006FU+0302;गॉ gô
U+0918U+0949<>U+0067U+0068U+006FU+0302;घॉ ghô
U+0919U+0949<>U+1E45U+006FU+0302;ङॉ ṅô
U+091AU+0949<>U+0063U+006FU+0302;चॉ cô
U+091BU+0949<>U+0063U+0068U+006FU+0302;छॉ chô
U+091CU+0949<>U+006AU+006FU+0302;जॉ jô
U+091DU+0949<>U+006AU+0068U+006FU+0302;झॉ jhô
U+091EU+0949<>U+00F1U+006FU+0302;ञॉ ñô
U+091FU+0949<>U+1E6DU+006FU+0302;टॉ ṭô
U+0920U+0949<>U+1E6DU+0068U+006FU+0302;ठॉ ṭhô
U+0921U+0949<>U+1E0DU+006FU+0302;डॉ ḍô
U+0922U+0949<>U+1E0DU+0068U+006FU+0302;ढॉ ḍhô
U+0923U+0949<>U+1E47U+006FU+0302;णॉ ṇô
U+0924U+0949<>U+0074U+006FU+0302;तॉ tô
U+0925U+0949<>U+0074U+0068U+006FU+0302;थॉ thô
U+0926U+0949<>U+0064U+006FU+0302;दॉ dô
U+0927U+0949<>U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0302;धॉ dhô
U+0928U+0949<>U+006EU+006FU+0302;नॉ nô
U+092AU+0949<>U+0070U+006FU+0302;पॉ pô
U+092BU+0949<>U+0070U+0068U+006FU+0302;फॉ phô
U+092CU+0949<>U+0062U+006FU+0302;बॉ bô
U+092DU+0949<>U+0062U+0068U+006FU+0302;भॉ bhô
U+092EU+0949<>U+006DU+006FU+0302;मॉ mô
U+092FU+0949<>U+0079U+006FU+0302;यॉ yô
U+0930U+0949<>U+0072U+006FU+0302;रॉ rô
U+0932U+0949<>U+006CU+006FU+0302;लॉ lô
U+0935U+0949<>U+0076U+006FU+0302;वॉ vô
U+0936U+0949<>U+015BU+006FU+0302;शॉ śô
U+0937U+0949<>U+1E63U+006FU+0302;षॉ ṣô
U+0938U+0949<>U+0073U+006FU+0302;सॉ sô
U+0939U+0949<>U+0068U+006FU+0302;हॉ hô
U+0958U+0949<>U+0071U+006FU+0302;क़ॉ qô
U+0959U+0949<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006FU+0302;ख़ॉ k͟hô
U+095AU+0949<>U+0121U+006FU+0302;ग़ॉ ġô
U+095BU+0949<>U+007AU+006FU+0302;ज़ॉ zô
U+095CU+0949<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0302;ड़ॉ dddhô
U+095DU+0949<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006FU+0302;ढ़ॉ ṛhô
U+095EU+0949<>U+0066U+006FU+0302;फ़ॉ fô
U+095FU+0949<>U+0079U+0079U+006FU+0302;य़ॉ yyô
U+0929U+0949<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+006FU+0302;ऩॉ nnnô
U+0931U+0949<>U+0072U+0072U+006FU+0302;ऱॉ rrô
U+0933U+0949<>U+1E37U+006FU+0302;ळॉ ḷô
U+0934U+0949<>U+1E3BU+006FU+0302;ऴॉ ḻô
U+0915U+0945<>U+006BU+0065U+0302;कॅ kê
U+0916U+0945<>U+006BU+0068U+0065U+0302;खॅ khê
U+0917U+0945<>U+0067U+0065U+0302;गॅ gê
U+0918U+0945<>U+0067U+0068U+0065U+0302;घॅ ghê
U+0919U+0945<>U+1E45U+0065U+0302;ङॅ ṅê
U+091AU+0945<>U+0063U+0065U+0302;चॅ cê
U+091BU+0945<>U+0063U+0068U+0065U+0302;छॅ chê
U+091CU+0945<>U+006AU+0065U+0302;जॅ jê
U+091DU+0945<>U+006AU+0068U+0065U+0302;झॅ jhê
U+091EU+0945<>U+00F1U+0065U+0302;ञॅ ñê
U+091FU+0945<>U+1E6DU+0065U+0302;टॅ ṭê
U+0920U+0945<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0065U+0302;ठॅ ṭhê
U+0921U+0945<>U+1E0DU+0065U+0302;डॅ ḍê
U+0922U+0945<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0065U+0302;ढॅ ḍhê
U+0923U+0945<>U+1E47U+0065U+0302;णॅ ṇê
U+0924U+0945<>U+0074U+0065U+0302;तॅ tê
U+0925U+0945<>U+0074U+0068U+0065U+0302;थॅ thê
U+0926U+0945<>U+0064U+0065U+0302;दॅ dê
U+0927U+0945<>U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0302;धॅ dhê
U+0928U+0945<>U+006EU+0065U+0302;नॅ nê
U+092AU+0945<>U+0070U+0065U+0302;पॅ pê
U+092BU+0945<>U+0070U+0068U+0065U+0302;फॅ phê
U+092CU+0945<>U+0062U+0065U+0302;बॅ bê
U+092DU+0945<>U+0062U+0068U+0065U+0302;भॅ bhê
U+092EU+0945<>U+006DU+0065U+0302;मॅ mê
U+092FU+0945<>U+0079U+0065U+0302;यॅ yê
U+0930U+0945<>U+0072U+0065U+0302;रॅ rê
U+0932U+0945<>U+006CU+0065U+0302;लॅ lê
U+0935U+0945<>U+0076U+0065U+0302;वॅ vê
U+0936U+0945<>U+015BU+0065U+0302;शॅ śê
U+0937U+0945<>U+1E63U+0065U+0302;षॅ ṣê
U+0938U+0945<>U+0073U+0065U+0302;सॅ sê
U+0939U+0945<>U+0068U+0065U+0302;हॅ hê
U+0958U+0945<>U+0071U+0065U+0302;क़ॅ qê
U+0959U+0945<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065U+0302;ख़ॅ k͟hê
U+095AU+0945<>U+0121U+0065U+0302;ग़ॅ ġê
U+095BU+0945<>U+007AU+0065U+0302;ज़ॅ zê
U+095CU+0945<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0302;ड़ॅ dddhê
U+095DU+0945<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065U+0302;ढ़ॅ ṛhê
U+095EU+0945<>U+0066U+0065U+0302;फ़ॅ fê
U+095FU+0945<>U+0079U+0079U+0065U+0302;य़ॅ yyê
U+0929U+0945<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0065U+0302;ऩॅ nnnê
U+0931U+0945<>U+0072U+0072U+0065U+0302;ऱॅ rrê
U+0933U+0945<>U+1E37U+0065U+0302;ळॅ ḷê
U+0934U+0945<>U+1E3BU+0065U+0302;ऴॅ ḻê
U+0915U+0955<>U+006BU+0065U+0304U+0302;कॕ kē̂
U+0916U+0955<>U+006BU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;खॕ khē̂
U+0917U+0955<>U+0067U+0065U+0304U+0302;गॕ gē̂
U+0918U+0955<>U+0067U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;घॕ ghē̂
U+0919U+0955<>U+1E45U+0065U+0304U+0302;ङॕ ṅē̂
U+091AU+0955<>U+0063U+0065U+0304U+0302;चॕ cē̂
U+091BU+0955<>U+0063U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;छॕ chē̂
U+091CU+0955<>U+006AU+0065U+0304U+0302;जॕ jē̂
U+091DU+0955<>U+006AU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;झॕ jhē̂
U+091EU+0955<>U+00F1U+0065U+0304U+0302;ञॕ ñē̂
U+091FU+0955<>U+1E6DU+0065U+0304U+0302;टॕ ṭē̂
U+0920U+0955<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;ठॕ ṭhē̂
U+0921U+0955<>U+1E0DU+0065U+0304U+0302;डॕ ḍē̂
U+0922U+0955<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;ढॕ ḍhē̂
U+0923U+0955<>U+1E47U+0065U+0304U+0302;णॕ ṇē̂
U+0924U+0955<>U+0074U+0065U+0304U+0302;तॕ tē̂
U+0925U+0955<>U+0074U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;थॕ thē̂
U+0926U+0955<>U+0064U+0065U+0304U+0302;दॕ dē̂
U+0927U+0955<>U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;धॕ dhē̂
U+0928U+0955<>U+006EU+0065U+0304U+0302;नॕ nē̂
U+092AU+0955<>U+0070U+0065U+0304U+0302;पॕ pē̂
U+092BU+0955<>U+0070U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;फॕ phē̂
U+092CU+0955<>U+0062U+0065U+0304U+0302;बॕ bē̂
U+092DU+0955<>U+0062U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;भॕ bhē̂
U+092EU+0955<>U+006DU+0065U+0304U+0302;मॕ mē̂
U+092FU+0955<>U+0079U+0065U+0304U+0302;यॕ yē̂
U+0930U+0955<>U+0072U+0065U+0304U+0302;रॕ rē̂
U+0932U+0955<>U+006CU+0065U+0304U+0302;लॕ lē̂
U+0935U+0955<>U+0076U+0065U+0304U+0302;वॕ vē̂
U+0936U+0955<>U+015BU+0065U+0304U+0302;शॕ śē̂
U+0937U+0955<>U+1E63U+0065U+0304U+0302;षॕ ṣē̂
U+0938U+0955<>U+0073U+0065U+0304U+0302;सॕ sē̂
U+0939U+0955<>U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;हॕ hē̂
U+0958U+0955<>U+0071U+0065U+0304U+0302;क़ॕ qē̂
U+0959U+0955<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;ख़ॕ k͟hē̂
U+095AU+0955<>U+0121U+0065U+0304U+0302;ग़ॕ ġē̂
U+095BU+0955<>U+007AU+0065U+0304U+0302;ज़ॕ zē̂
U+095CU+0955<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0306;ड़ॕ dddhē̂
U+095DU+0955<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;ढ़ॕ ṛhē̂
U+095EU+0955<>U+0066U+0065U+0304U+0302;फ़ॕ fē̂
U+095FU+0955<>U+0079U+0079U+0065U+0304U+0302;य़ॕ yyē̂
U+0929U+0955<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0065U+0304U+0302;ऩॕ nnnē̂
U+0931U+0955<>U+0072U+0072U+0065U+0304U+0302;ऱॕ rrē̂
U+0933U+0955<>U+1E37U+0065U+0304U+0302;ळॕ ḷē̂
U+0934U+0955<>U+1E3BU+0065U+0304U+0302;ऴॕ ḻē̂
U+0915U+094E<>U+006BU+0119;कॎ kę
U+0916U+094E<>U+006BU+0068U+0119;खॎ khę
U+0917U+094E<>U+0067U+0119;गॎ gę
U+0918U+094E<>U+0067U+0068U+0119;घॎ ghę
U+0919U+094E<>U+1E45U+0119;ङॎ ṅę
U+091AU+094E<>U+0063U+0119;चॎ cę
U+091BU+094E<>U+0063U+0068U+0119;छॎ chę
U+091CU+094E<>U+006AU+0119;जॎ ję
U+091DU+094E<>U+006AU+0068U+0119;झॎ jhę
U+091EU+094E<>U+00F1U+0119;ञॎ ñę
U+091FU+094E<>U+1E6DU+0119;टॎ ṭę
U+0920U+094E<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0119;ठॎ ṭhę
U+0921U+094E<>U+1E0DU+0119;डॎ ḍę
U+0922U+094E<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0119;ढॎ ḍhę
U+0923U+094E<>U+1E47U+0119;णॎ ṇę
U+0924U+094E<>U+0074U+0119;तॎ tę
U+0925U+094E<>U+0074U+0068U+0119;थॎ thę
U+0926U+094E<>U+0064U+0119;दॎ dę
U+0927U+094E<>U+0064U+0068U+0119;धॎ dhę
U+0928U+094E<>U+006EU+0119;नॎ nę
U+092AU+094E<>U+0070U+0119;पॎ pę
U+092BU+094E<>U+0070U+0068U+0119;फॎ phę
U+092CU+094E<>U+0062U+0119;बॎ bę
U+092DU+094E<>U+0062U+0068U+0119;भॎ bhę
U+092EU+094E<>U+006DU+0119;मॎ mę
U+092FU+094E<>U+0079U+0119;यॎ yę
U+0930U+094E<>U+0072U+0119;रॎ rę
U+0932U+094E<>U+006CU+0119;लॎ lę
U+0935U+094E<>U+0076U+0119;वॎ vę
U+0936U+094E<>U+015BU+0119;शॎ śę
U+0937U+094E<>U+1E63U+0119;षॎ ṣę
U+0938U+094E<>U+0073U+0119;सॎ sę
U+0939U+094E<>U+0068U+0119;हॎ hę
U+0958U+094E<>U+0071U+0119;क़ॎ qę
U+0959U+094E<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0119;ख़ॎ k͟hę
U+095AU+094E<>U+0121U+0119;ग़ॎ ġę
U+095BU+094E<>U+007AU+0119;ज़ॎ zę
U+095CU+094E<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0119;ड़ॎ dddhę
U+095DU+094E<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0119;ढ़ॎ ṛhę
U+095EU+094E<>U+0066U+0119;फ़ॎ fę
U+095FU+094E<>U+0079U+0079U+0119;य़ॎ yyę
U+0929U+094E<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0119;ऩॎ nnnę
U+0931U+094E<>U+0072U+0072U+0119;ऱॎ rrę
U+0933U+094E<>U+1E37U+0119;ळॎ ḷę
U+0934U+094E<>U+1E3BU+0119;ऴॎ ḻę
U+092BU+093CU+094D<>U+0066;फ़् f
U+092BU+093C<>U+0066U+0061;फ़ fa
U+092BU+093CU+0941<>U+0066U+0075;फ़ु fu
U+092BU+093CU+0942<>U+0066U+016B;फ़ू fū
U+092BU+093CU+0943<>U+0066U+1E5B;फ़ृ fṛ
U+092BU+093CU+0944<>U+0066U+1E5D;फ़ॄ fṝ
U+092BU+093CU+093E<>U+0066U+0101;फ़ा fā
U+092BU+093CU+0947<>U+0066U+0065;फ़े fe
U+092BU+093CU+093F<>U+0066U+0069;फ़ि fi
U+092BU+093CU+0940<>U+0066U+012B;फ़ी fī
U+092BU+093CU+094B<>U+0066U+006F;फ़ो fo
U+092BU+093CU+0948<>U+0066U+0061U+0069;फ़ै fai
U+092BU+093CU+093A<>U+0066U+006FU+0065;फ़ऺ foe
U+092BU+093CU+093B<>U+0066U+014DU+0065;फ़ऻ fōe
U+092BU+093CU+0946<>U+0066U+0065U+0306;फ़ॆ fĕ
U+092BU+093CU+094A<>U+0066U+006FU+0306;फ़ॊ fŏ
U+092BU+093CU+094C<>U+0066U+0061U+0075;फ़ौ fau
U+092BU+093CU+094F<>U+0066U+0061U+0077;फ़ॏ faw
U+092BU+093CU+0956<>U+0066U+0075U+0065;फ़ॖ fue
U+092BU+093CU+0957<>U+0066U+016BU+0065;फ़ॗ fūe
U+092BU+093CU+0962<>U+0066U+1E37;फ़ॢ fḷ
U+092BU+093CU+0963<>U+0066U+1E39;फ़ॣ fḹ
U+092BU+093CU+0949<>U+0066U+006FU+0302;फ़ॉ fô
U+092BU+093CU+0945<>U+0066U+0065U+0302;फ़ॅ fê
U+092BU+093CU+0955<>U+0066U+0065U+0304U+0302;फ़ॕ fē̂
U+092BU+093CU+094E<>U+0066U+0119;फ़ॎ fę
U+0916U+093CU+094D<>U+006BU+035FU+0068;ख़् k͟h
U+0916U+093C<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061;ख़ k͟ha
U+0916U+093CU+0941<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0075;ख़ु k͟hu
U+0916U+093CU+0942<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+016B;ख़ू k͟hū
U+0916U+093CU+0943<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E5B;ख़ृ k͟hṛ
U+0916U+093CU+0944<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E5D;ख़ॄ k͟hṝ
U+0916U+093CU+093E<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0101;ख़ा k͟hā
U+0916U+093CU+0947<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065;ख़े k͟he
U+0916U+093CU+093F<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0069;ख़ि k͟hi
U+0916U+093CU+0940<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+012B;ख़ी k͟hī
U+0916U+093CU+094B<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006F;ख़ो k͟ho
U+0916U+093CU+0948<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061U+0069;ख़ै k͟hai
U+0916U+093CU+093A<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006FU+0065;ख़ऺ k͟hoe
U+0916U+093CU+093B<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+014DU+0065;ख़ऻ k͟hōe
U+0916U+093CU+0946<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065U+0306;ख़ॆ k͟hĕ
U+0916U+093CU+094A<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006FU+0306;ख़ॊ k͟hŏ
U+0916U+093CU+094C<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061U+0075;ख़ौ k͟hau
U+0916U+093CU+094F<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061U+0077;ख़ॏ k͟haw
U+0916U+093CU+0956<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0075U+0065;ख़ॖ k͟hue
U+0916U+093CU+0957<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+016BU+0065;ख़ॗ k͟hūe
U+0916U+093CU+0962<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E37;ख़ॢ k͟hḷ
U+0916U+093CU+0963<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E39;ख़ॣ k͟hḹ
U+0916U+093CU+0949<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006FU+0302;ख़ॉ k͟hô
U+0916U+093CU+0945<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065U+0302;ख़ॅ k͟hê
U+0916U+093CU+0955<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;ख़ॕ k͟hē̂
U+0916U+093CU+094E<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0119;ख़ॎ k͟hę
U+0915U+093CU+094D<>U+0071;क़् q
U+0915U+093C<>U+0071U+0061;क़ qa
U+0915U+093CU+0941<>U+0071U+0075;क़ु qu
U+0915U+093CU+0942<>U+0071U+016B;क़ू qū
U+0915U+093CU+0943<>U+0071U+1E5B;क़ृ qṛ
U+0915U+093CU+0944<>U+0071U+1E5D;क़ॄ qṝ
U+0915U+093CU+093E<>U+0071U+0101;क़ा qā
U+0915U+093CU+0947<>U+0071U+0065;क़े qe
U+0915U+093CU+093F<>U+0071U+0069;क़ि qi
U+0915U+093CU+0940<>U+0071U+012B;क़ी qī
U+0915U+093CU+094B<>U+0071U+006F;क़ो qo
U+0915U+093CU+0948<>U+0071U+0061U+0069;क़ै qai
U+0915U+093CU+093A<>U+0071U+006FU+0065;क़ऺ qoe
U+0915U+093CU+093B<>U+0071U+014DU+0065;क़ऻ qōe
U+0915U+093CU+0946<>U+0071U+0065U+0306;क़ॆ qĕ
U+0915U+093CU+094A<>U+0071U+006FU+0306;क़ॊ qŏ
U+0915U+093CU+094C<>U+0071U+0061U+0075;क़ौ qau
U+0915U+093CU+094F<>U+0071U+0061U+0077;क़ॏ qaw
U+0915U+093CU+0956<>U+0071U+0075U+0065;क़ॖ que
U+0915U+093CU+0957<>U+0071U+016BU+0065;क़ॗ qūe
U+0915U+093CU+0962<>U+0071U+1E37;क़ॢ qḷ
U+0915U+093CU+0963<>U+0071U+1E39;क़ॣ qḹ
U+0915U+093CU+0949<>U+0071U+006FU+0302;क़ॉ qô
U+0915U+093CU+0945<>U+0071U+0065U+0302;क़ॅ qê
U+0915U+093CU+0955<>U+0071U+0065U+0304U+0302;क़ॕ qē̂
U+0915U+093CU+094E<>U+0071U+0119;क़ॎ qę
U+0917U+093CU+094D<>U+0121;ग़् ġ
U+0917U+093C<>U+0121U+0061;ग़ ġa
U+0917U+093CU+0941<>U+0121U+0075;ग़ु ġu
U+0917U+093CU+0942<>U+0121U+016B;ग़ू ġū
U+0917U+093CU+0943<>U+0121U+1E5B;ग़ृ ġṛ
U+0917U+093CU+0944<>U+0121U+1E5D;ग़ॄ ġṝ
U+0917U+093CU+093E<>U+0121U+0101;ग़ा ġā
U+0917U+093CU+0947<>U+0121U+0065;ग़े ġe
U+0917U+093CU+093F<>U+0121U+0069;ग़ि ġi
U+0917U+093CU+0940<>U+0121U+012B;ग़ी ġī
U+0917U+093CU+094B<>U+0121U+006F;ग़ो ġo
U+0917U+093CU+0948<>U+0121U+0061U+0069;ग़ै ġai
U+0917U+093CU+093A<>U+0121U+006FU+0065;ग़ऺ ġoe
U+0917U+093CU+093B<>U+0121U+014DU+0065;ग़ऻ ġōe
U+0917U+093CU+0946<>U+0121U+0065U+0306;ग़ॆ ġĕ
U+0917U+093CU+094A<>U+0121U+006FU+0306;ग़ॊ ġŏ
U+0917U+093CU+094C<>U+0121U+0061U+0075;ग़ौ ġau
U+0917U+093CU+094F<>U+0121U+0061U+0077;ग़ॏ ġaw
U+0917U+093CU+0956<>U+0121U+0075U+0065;ग़ॖ ġue
U+0917U+093CU+0957<>U+0121U+016BU+0065;ग़ॗ ġūe
U+0917U+093CU+0962<>U+0121U+1E37;ग़ॢ ġḷ
U+0917U+093CU+0963<>U+0121U+1E39;ग़ॣ ġḹ
U+0917U+093CU+0949<>U+0121U+006FU+0302;ग़ॉ ġô
U+0917U+093CU+0945<>U+0121U+0065U+0302;ग़ॅ ġê
U+0917U+093CU+0955<>U+0121U+0065U+0304U+0302;ग़ॕ ġē̂
U+0917U+093CU+094E<>U+0121U+0119;ग़ॎ ġę
U+091CU+093CU+094D<>U+007A;ज़् z
U+091CU+093C<>U+007AU+0061;ज़ za
U+091CU+093CU+0941<>U+007AU+0075;ज़ु zu
U+091CU+093CU+0942<>U+007AU+016B;ज़ू zū
U+091CU+093CU+0943<>U+007AU+1E5B;ज़ृ zṛ
U+091CU+093CU+0944<>U+007AU+1E5D;ज़ॄ zṝ
U+091CU+093CU+093E<>U+007AU+0101;ज़ा zā
U+091CU+093CU+0947<>U+007AU+0065;ज़े ze
U+091CU+093CU+093F<>U+007AU+0069;ज़ि zi
U+091CU+093CU+0940<>U+007AU+012B;ज़ी zī
U+091CU+093CU+094B<>U+007AU+006F;ज़ो zo
U+091CU+093CU+0948<>U+007AU+0061U+0069;ज़ै zai
U+091CU+093CU+093A<>U+007AU+006FU+0065;ज़ऺ zoe
U+091CU+093CU+093B<>U+007AU+014DU+0065;ज़ऻ zōe
U+091CU+093CU+0946<>U+007AU+0065U+0306;ज़ॆ zĕ
U+091CU+093CU+094A<>U+007AU+006FU+0306;ज़ॊ zŏ
U+091CU+093CU+094C<>U+007AU+0061U+0075;ज़ौ zau
U+091CU+093CU+094F<>U+007AU+0061U+0077;ज़ॏ zaw
U+091CU+093CU+0956<>U+007AU+0075U+0065;ज़ॖ zue
U+091CU+093CU+0957<>U+007AU+016BU+0065;ज़ॗ zūe
U+091CU+093CU+0962<>U+007AU+1E37;ज़ॢ zḷ
U+091CU+093CU+0963<>U+007AU+1E39;ज़ॣ zḹ
U+091CU+093CU+0949<>U+007AU+006FU+0302;ज़ॉ zô
U+091CU+093CU+0945<>U+007AU+0065U+0302;ज़ॅ zê
U+091CU+093CU+0955<>U+007AU+0065U+0304U+0302;ज़ॕ zē̂
U+091CU+093CU+094E<>U+007AU+0119;ज़ॎ zę
U+0921U+093CU+094D<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068;ड़् dddh
U+0921U+093C<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061;ड़ dddha
U+0921U+093CU+0941<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0075;ड़ु dddhu
U+0921U+093CU+0942<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+016B;ड़ू dddhū
U+0921U+093CU+0943<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E5B;ड़ृ dddhṛ
U+0921U+093CU+0944<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E5D;ड़ॄ dddhṝ
U+0921U+093CU+093E<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0101;ड़ा dddhā
U+0921U+093CU+0947<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065;ड़े dddhe
U+0921U+093CU+093F<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0069;ड़ि dddhi
U+0921U+093CU+0940<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+012B;ड़ी dddhī
U+0921U+093CU+094B<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006F;ड़ो dddho
U+0921U+093CU+0948<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0069;ड़ै dddhai
U+0921U+093CU+093A<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0065;ड़ऺ dddhoe
U+0921U+093CU+093B<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+014DU+0065;ड़ऻ dddhōe
U+0921U+093CU+0946<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0306;ड़ॆ dddhĕ
U+0921U+093CU+094A<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0306;ड़ॊ dddhŏ
U+0921U+093CU+094C<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0075;ड़ौ dddhau
U+0921U+093CU+094F<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0077;ड़ॏ dddhaw
U+0921U+093CU+0956<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0075U+0065;ड़ॖ dddhue
U+0921U+093CU+0957<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+016BU+0065;ड़ॗ dddhūe
U+0921U+093CU+0962<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E37;ड़ॢ dddhḷ
U+0921U+093CU+0963<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E39;ड़ॣ dddhḹ
U+0921U+093CU+0949<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0302;ड़ॉ dddhô
U+0921U+093CU+0945<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0302;ड़ॅ dddhê
U+0921U+093CU+0955<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;ड़ॕ dddhē̂
U+0921U+093CU+094E<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0119;ड़ॎ dddhę
U+0922U+093CU+094D<>U+1E5BU+0068;ढ़् ṛh
U+0922U+093C<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061;ढ़ ṛha
U+0922U+093CU+0941<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0075;ढ़ु ṛhu
U+0922U+093CU+0942<>U+1E5BU+0068U+016B;ढ़ू ṛhū
U+0922U+093CU+0943<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E5B;ढ़ृ ṛhṛ
U+0922U+093CU+0944<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E5D;ढ़ॄ ṛhṝ
U+0922U+093CU+093E<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0101;ढ़ा ṛhā
U+0922U+093CU+0947<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065;ढ़े ṛhe
U+0922U+093CU+093F<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0069;ढ़ि ṛhi
U+0922U+093CU+0940<>U+1E5BU+0068U+012B;ढ़ी ṛhī
U+0922U+093CU+094B<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006F;ढ़ो ṛho
U+0922U+093CU+0948<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061U+0069;ढ़ै ṛhai
U+0922U+093CU+093A<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006FU+0065;ढ़ऺ ṛhoe
U+0922U+093CU+093B<>U+1E5BU+0068U+014DU+0065;ढ़ऻ ṛhōe
U+0922U+093CU+0946<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065U+0306;ढ़ॆ ṛhĕ
U+0922U+093CU+094A<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006FU+0306;ढ़ॊ ṛhŏ
U+0922U+093CU+094C<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061U+0075;ढ़ौ ṛhau
U+0922U+093CU+094F<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061U+0077;ढ़ॏ ṛhaw
U+0922U+093CU+0956<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0075U+0065;ढ़ॖ ṛhue
U+0922U+093CU+0957<>U+1E5BU+0068U+016BU+0065;ढ़ॗ ṛhūe
U+0922U+093CU+0962<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E37;ढ़ॢ ṛhḷ
U+0922U+093CU+0963<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E39;ढ़ॣ ṛhḹ
U+0922U+093CU+0949<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006FU+0302;ढ़ॉ ṛhô
U+0922U+093CU+0945<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065U+0302;ढ़ॅ ṛhê
U+0922U+093CU+0955<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065U+0304U+0302;ढ़ॕ ṛhē̂
U+0922U+093CU+094E<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0119;ढ़ॎ ṛhę
U+092FU+093CU+094D<>U+0079U+0079;य़् yy
U+092FU+093C<>U+0079U+0079U+0061;य़ yya
U+092FU+093CU+0941<>U+0079U+0079U+0075;य़ु yyu
U+092FU+093CU+0942<>U+0079U+0079U+016B;य़ू yyū
U+092FU+093CU+0943<>U+0079U+0079U+1E5B;य़ृ yyṛ
U+092FU+093CU+0944<>U+0079U+0079U+1E5D;य़ॄ yyṝ
U+092FU+093CU+093E<>U+0079U+0079U+0101;य़ा yyā
U+092FU+093CU+0947<>U+0079U+0079U+0065;य़े yye
U+092FU+093CU+093F<>U+0079U+0079U+0069;य़ि yyi
U+092FU+093CU+0940<>U+0079U+0079U+012B;य़ी yyī
U+092FU+093CU+094B<>U+0079U+0079U+006F;य़ो yyo
U+092FU+093CU+0948<>U+0079U+0079U+0061U+0069;य़ै yyai
U+092FU+093CU+093A<>U+0079U+0079U+006FU+0065;य़ऺ yyoe
U+092FU+093CU+093B<>U+0079U+0079U+014DU+0065;य़ऻ yyōe
U+092FU+093CU+0946<>U+0079U+0079U+0065U+0306;य़ॆ yyĕ
U+092FU+093CU+094A<>U+0079U+0079U+006FU+0306;य़ॊ yyŏ
U+092FU+093CU+094C<>U+0079U+0079U+0061U+0075;य़ौ yyau
U+092FU+093CU+094F<>U+0079U+0079U+0061U+0077;य़ॏ yyaw
U+092FU+093CU+0956<>U+0079U+0079U+0075U+0065;य़ॖ yyue
U+092FU+093CU+0957<>U+0079U+0079U+016BU+0065;य़ॗ yyūe
U+092FU+093CU+0962<>U+0079U+0079U+1E37;य़ॢ yyḷ
U+092FU+093CU+0963<>U+0079U+0079U+1E39;य़ॣ yyḹ
U+092FU+093CU+0949<>U+0079U+0079U+006FU+0302;य़ॉ yyô
U+092FU+093CU+0945<>U+0079U+0079U+0065U+0302;य़ॅ yyê
U+092FU+093CU+0955<>U+0079U+0079U+0065U+0304U+0302;य़ॕ yyē̂
U+092FU+093CU+094E<>U+0079U+0079U+0119;य़ॎ yyę
```

[image: test sentence]

Comment: I've added the solution in a GIST and linked in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without using iast.map (that code is somewhat complicated to take in quickly), a simple IAST-based mapping file shows it is possible:

[image: iast based]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontface\translitd[Mapping=devanagari-to-iastb,Colour=red]{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\Large
संयुक्त व्यंजन =
{\normalsize\textenglish{sanyukt vyanjan}}

{\normalsize\textenglish{IAST-based transliteration:}}

{\translitd संयुक्त}\index{{\translitd संयुक्त}}
{\translitd व्यंजन}\index{{\translitd व्यंजन}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `devanagari-to-iastb.map` file (so far):

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "devanagari-to-iastb" ; IAST+supplemental material
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET



U+0905    <> U+0061    ;  अ a
U+0906    <> U+0101    ;  आ ā
U+0907    <> U+0069    ;  इ i
U+0908    <> U+012B    ;  ई ī
U+0909    <> U+0075    ;  उ u
U+090A    <> U+016B    ;  ऊ ū
U+090F    <> U+0065    ;  ए e
U+0910    <> U+0061 U+0069   ;  ऐ ai
U+0913    <> U+006F    ;  ओ o
U+0914    <> U+0061 U+0075   ;  औ au
U+090B    <> U+1E5B    ;  ऋ ṛ
U+0960    <> U+1E5D    ;  ॠ ṝ
U+090C    <> U+1E37    ;  ऌ ḷ
U+0961    <> U+1E39    ;  ॡ ḹ
U+0905 U+0902   <> U+1E43    ;  अं ṃ
U+0905 U+0903   <> U+1E25    ;  अः ḥ
U+0905 U+0901   <> U+0058    ;  अँ X
U+093D    <> U+0027    ;  ऽ '
U+0915    <> U+006B U+0061   ;  क ka
U+0916    <> U+006B U+0068 U+0061  ;  ख kha
U+0917    <> U+0067 U+0061   ;  ग ga
U+0918    <> U+0067 U+0068 U+0061  ;  घ gha
U+0919    <> U+1E45 U+0061   ;  ङ ṅa
U+091A    <> U+0063 U+0061   ;  च ca
U+091B    <> U+0063 U+0068 U+0061  ;  छ cha
U+091C    <> U+006A U+0061   ;  ज ja
U+091D    <> U+006A U+0068 U+0061  ;  झ jha
U+091E    <> U+00F1 U+0061   ;  ञ ña
U+091F    <> U+1E6D U+0061   ;  ट ṭa
U+0920    <> U+1E6D U+0068 U+0061  ;  ठ ṭha
U+0921    <> U+1E0D U+0061   ;  ड ḍa
U+0922    <> U+1E0D U+0068 U+0061  ;  ढ ḍha
U+0923    <> U+1E47 U+0061   ;  ण ṇa
U+0924    <> U+0074 U+0061   ;  त ta
U+0925    <> U+0074 U+0068 U+0061  ;  थ tha
U+0926    <> U+0064 U+0061   ;  द da
U+0927    <> U+0064 U+0068 U+0061  ;  ध dha
U+0928    <> U+006E U+0061   ;  न na
U+092A    <> U+0070 U+0061   ;  प pa
U+092B    <> U+0070 U+0068 U+0061  ;  फ pha
U+092C    <> U+0062 U+0061   ;  ब ba
U+092D    <> U+0062 U+0068 U+0061  ;  भ bha
U+092E    <> U+006D U+0061   ;  म ma
U+092F    <> U+0079 U+0061   ;  य ya
U+0930    <> U+0072 U+0061   ;  र ra
U+0932    <> U+006C U+0061   ;  ल la
U+0935    <> U+0076 U+0061   ;  व va
U+0936    <> U+015B U+0061   ;  श śa
U+0937    <> U+1E63 U+0061   ;  ष ṣa
U+0938    <> U+0073 U+0061   ;  स sa
U+0939    <> U+0068 U+0061   ;  ह ha
U+0915 U+093C   <> U+0071 U+0061   ;  क़ qa
U+0916 U+093C   <> U+006B U+035F U+0068  ;  ख़ k͟ha
U+0917 U+093C   <> U+0121 U+0061   ;  ग़ ġa
U+091C U+093C   <> U+007A U+0061   ;  ज़ za
U+092B U+093C   <> U+0066 U+0061   ;  फ़ fa
U+0921 U+093C   <> U+1E5B U+0061   ;  ड़ ṛa
U+0922 U+093C   <> U+1E5B U+0068 U+0061  ;  ढ़ ṛha
;=============================
U+0902 <> U+006E U+0323 ; n.
;=============================
; u
U+092F U+0941 <> U+0079 U+0075 ; yu
;=============================
; no a
; U+094D
U+0915 U+094D <> U+006B ; k
U+0935 U+094D <> U+0076 ; v
```

Looks like IAST was done for the pen-and-paper days, when the human filled in the obvious transliterations.

It's more efficient to let the computer do it all, so I'll fill in the rest of the combinations over the next week or so. It makes it much easier to maintain as well (e.g., it just becomes a copy-paste in the end).

Also, from a very quick glance, I think IAST may have some gaps.

---

Edited to add:

Map file creation proceeding quite well. It can handle the first sentence of the conjunct consonants article on Wikipedia. A transliteration convention: The word-final `-a` is not often pronounced nowadays, so a bit like the word-final `-e` in English: silent.

[image: deva progress report 1]

I'll post the map file as a separate answer, for ease of use from its size, and continue updating it over the next few days.

---

Mapping file can now handle the test sentence:

[image: test sentence]

---

Final update: Mapping file is complete enough to be practical for use, and done in plain style for ease of update/changes if required.  IAST is lossless transliteration. What I originally presumed were 'gaps' were just modern letters, after IAST was developed, I'm guessing - I have added those in as well, following the IAST schema, including adding both series of the nuqta consonants (they have their own unicode slots, as well as the combinations of consonant + nuqta, like Wikipedia uses (and probably other pages)).

---

Addendum:

The reverse direction, from Roman to Devanagari, is just the mapping file's left-hand-side and right-hand side swapped over.

Since I don't have a IAST keyboard, with all the dots and macrons and so on, I made a slightly modified reverse-IAST using plain keyboard keys (`long a` is input as `aa`, e.g.), with the outcome in blue:

[image: back and forth]

Now, all Devanagari system fonts become available.

Cool [image: cool]

And adding in the Vedic material is equally straightforward.

The result of having a good teacher as an example is that the lesson becomes smoother (and also enjoyable). And this site is a good teacher.

Answer (score 0):

A plain simple mapping file, Devanagari to a IAST-based transliteration.

Edited to add: Done.

I have also added in modern letters. IAST is lossless transliteration: one to one.

Coverage:

[image: map coverage]

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "devanagari-to-iastb" ; IAST+supplemental material
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

U+0905<>U+0061;अ a
U+0906<>U+0101;आ ā
U+0907<>U+0069;इ i
U+0908<>U+012B;ई ī
U+0909<>U+0075;उ u
U+090A<>U+016B;ऊ ū
U+090F<>U+0065;ए e
U+0910<>U+0061U+0069;ऐ ai
U+0913<>U+006F;ओ o
U+0914<>U+0061U+0075;औ au
U+090B<>U+1E5B;ऋ ṛ
U+0960<>U+1E5D;ॠ ṝ
U+090C<>U+1E37;ऌ ḷ
U+0961<>U+1E39;ॡ ḹ
U+0905U+0902<>U+1E43;अं ṃ
U+0905U+0903<>U+1E25;अः ḥ
U+0905U+0901<>U+006FU+0302;अँ ô
U+0901<>U+0310;ँ ̐
U+0964<>U+007C;। |
U+0903<>U+1E25;ः ḥ
U+0912<>U+006FU+0306;ऒ ŏ
U+090E<>U+0065U+0306;ऎ ĕ
U+0904<>U+0061U+0306;ऄ ă
U+0965<>U+007CU+007C;॥ ||
U+096F<>U+0039;९ 9
U+096E<>U+0038;८ 8
U+096D<>U+0037;७ 7
U+096C<>U+0036;६ 6
U+096B<>U+0035;५ 5
U+096A<>U+0034;४ 4
U+0969<>U+0033;३ 3
U+0968<>U+0032;२ 2
U+0967<>U+0031;१ 1
U+0966<>U+0030;० 0
U+0951<>U+030D;॑ ̍
U+0952<>U+0331;॒ ̱
U+0953<>U+0300;॓ ̀
U+0954<>U+0301;॔ ́
U+0900<>U+0352;ऀ ͒
U+0902<>U+1E43;ं ṃ
U+090D<>U+0065U+0302;ऍ ê
U+0911<>U+006FU+0302;ऑ ô
U+093D<>U+0027;ऽ '
U+0915<>U+006BU+0061;क ka
U+0916<>U+006BU+0068U+0061;ख kha
U+0917<>U+0067U+0061;ग ga
U+0918<>U+0067U+0068U+0061;घ gha
U+0919<>U+1E45U+0061;ङ ṅa
U+091A<>U+0063U+0061;च ca
U+091B<>U+0063U+0068U+0061;छ cha
U+091C<>U+006AU+0061;ज ja
U+091D<>U+006AU+0068U+0061;झ jha
U+091E<>U+00F1U+0061;ञ ña
U+091F<>U+1E6DU+0061;ट ṭa
U+0920<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0061;ठ ṭha
U+0921<>U+1E0DU+0061;ड ḍa
U+0922<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0061;ढ ḍha
U+0923<>U+1E47U+0061;ण ṇa
U+0924<>U+0074U+0061;त ta
U+0925<>U+0074U+0068U+0061;थ tha
U+0926<>U+0064U+0061;द da
U+0927<>U+0064U+0068U+0061;ध dha
U+0928<>U+006EU+0061;न na
U+092A<>U+0070U+0061;प pa
U+092B<>U+0070U+0068U+0061;फ pha
U+092C<>U+0062U+0061;ब ba
U+092D<>U+0062U+0068U+0061;भ bha
U+092E<>U+006DU+0061;म ma
U+092F<>U+0079U+0061;य ya
U+0930<>U+0072U+0061;र ra
U+0932<>U+006CU+0061;ल la
U+0935<>U+0076U+0061;व va
U+0936<>U+015BU+0061;श śa
U+0937<>U+1E63U+0061;ष ṣa
U+0938<>U+0073U+0061;स sa
U+0939<>U+0068U+0061;ह ha
U+0958<>U+0071U+0061;क़ qa
U+0959<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061;ख़ k͟ha
U+095A<>U+0121U+0061;ग़ ġa
U+095B<>U+007AU+0061;ज़ za
U+095C<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061;ड़ dddha
U+095D<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061;ढ़ ṛha
U+095E<>U+0066U+0061;फ़ fa
U+095F<>U+0079U+0079U+0061;य़ yya
U+0929<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0061;ऩ nnna
U+0931<>U+0072U+0072U+0061;ऱ rra
U+0933<>U+1E37U+0061;ळ ḷa
U+0934<>U+1E3BU+0061;ऴ ḻa
U+0915U+094D<>U+006B;क् k
U+0916U+094D<>U+006BU+0068;ख् kh
U+0917U+094D<>U+0067;ग् g
U+0918U+094D<>U+0067U+0068;घ् gh
U+0919U+094D<>U+1E45;ङ् ṅ
U+091AU+094D<>U+0063;च् c
U+091BU+094D<>U+0063U+0068;छ् ch
U+091CU+094D<>U+006A;ज् j
U+091DU+094D<>U+006AU+0068;झ् jh
U+091EU+094D<>U+00F1;ञ् ñ
U+091FU+094D<>U+1E6D;ट् ṭ
U+0920U+094D<>U+1E6DU+0068;ठ् ṭh
U+0921U+094D<>U+1E0D;ड् ḍ
U+0922U+094D<>U+1E0DU+0068;ढ् ḍh
U+0923U+094D<>U+1E47;ण् ṇ
U+0924U+094D<>U+0074;त् t
U+0925U+094D<>U+0074U+0068;थ् th
U+0926U+094D<>U+0064;द् d
U+0927U+094D<>U+0064U+0068;ध् dh
U+0928U+094D<>U+006E;न् n
U+092AU+094D<>U+0070;प् p
U+092BU+094D<>U+0070U+0068;फ् ph
U+092CU+094D<>U+0062;ब् b
U+092DU+094D<>U+0062U+0068;भ् bh
U+092EU+094D<>U+006D;म् m
U+092FU+094D<>U+0079;य् y
U+0930U+094D<>U+0072;र् r
U+0932U+094D<>U+006C;ल् l
U+0935U+094D<>U+0076;व् v
U+0936U+094D<>U+015B;श् ś
U+0937U+094D<>U+1E63;ष् ṣ
U+0938U+094D<>U+0073;स् s
U+0939U+094D<>U+0068;ह् h
U+0958U+094D<>U+0071;क़् q
U+0959U+094D<>U+006BU+035FU+0068;ख़् k͟h
U+095AU+094D<>U+0121;ग़् ġ
U+095BU+094D<>U+007A;ज़् z
U+095CU+094D<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068;ड़् dddh
U+095DU+094D<>U+1E5BU+0068;ढ़् ṛh
U+095EU+094D<>U+0066;फ़् f
U+095FU+094D<>U+0079U+0079;य़् yy
U+0929U+094D<>U+006EU+006EU+006E;ऩ् nnn
U+0931U+094D<>U+0072U+0072;ऱ् rr
U+0933U+094D<>U+1E37;ळ् ḷ
U+0934U+094D<>U+1E3B;ऴ् ḻ
U+0915U+0941<>U+006BU+0075;कु ku
U+0916U+0941<>U+006BU+0068U+0075;खु khu
U+0917U+0941<>U+0067U+0075;गु gu
U+0918U+0941<>U+0067U+0068U+0075;घु ghu
U+0919U+0941<>U+1E45U+0075;ङु ṅu
U+091AU+0941<>U+0063U+0075;चु cu
U+091BU+0941<>U+0063U+0068U+0075;छु chu
U+091CU+0941<>U+006AU+0075;जु ju
U+091DU+0941<>U+006AU+0068U+0075;झु jhu
U+091EU+0941<>U+00F1U+0075;ञु ñu
U+091FU+0941<>U+1E6DU+0075;टु ṭu
U+0920U+0941<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0075;ठु ṭhu
U+0921U+0941<>U+1E0DU+0075;डु ḍu
U+0922U+0941<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0075;ढु ḍhu
U+0923U+0941<>U+1E47U+0075;णु ṇu
U+0924U+0941<>U+0074U+0075;तु tu
U+0925U+0941<>U+0074U+0068U+0075;थु thu
U+0926U+0941<>U+0064U+0075;दु du
U+0927U+0941<>U+0064U+0068U+0075;धु dhu
U+0928U+0941<>U+006EU+0075;नु nu
U+092AU+0941<>U+0070U+0075;पु pu
U+092BU+0941<>U+0070U+0068U+0075;फु phu
U+092CU+0941<>U+0062U+0075;बु bu
U+092DU+0941<>U+0062U+0068U+0075;भु bhu
U+092EU+0941<>U+006DU+0075;मु mu
U+092FU+0941<>U+0079U+0075;यु yu
U+0930U+0941<>U+0072U+0075;रु ru
U+0932U+0941<>U+006CU+0075;लु lu
U+0935U+0941<>U+0076U+0075;वु vu
U+0936U+0941<>U+015BU+0075;शु śu
U+0937U+0941<>U+1E63U+0075;षु ṣu
U+0938U+0941<>U+0073U+0075;सु su
U+0939U+0941<>U+0068U+0075;हु hu
U+0958U+0941<>U+0071U+0075;क़ु qu
U+0959U+0941<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0075;ख़ु k͟hu
U+095AU+0941<>U+0121U+0075;ग़ु ġu
U+095BU+0941<>U+007AU+0075;ज़ु zu
U+095CU+0941<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0075;ड़ु dddhu
U+095DU+0941<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0075;ढ़ु ṛhu
U+095EU+0941<>U+0066U+0075;फ़ु fu
U+095FU+0941<>U+0079U+0079U+0075;य़ु yyu
U+0929U+0941<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0075;ऩु nnnu
U+0931U+0941<>U+0072U+0072U+0075;ऱु rru
U+0933U+0941<>U+1E37U+0075;ळु ḷu
U+0934U+0941<>U+1E3BU+0075;ऴु ḻu
U+0915U+0942<>U+006BU+016B;कू kū
U+0916U+0942<>U+006BU+0068U+016B;खू khū
U+0917U+0942<>U+0067U+016B;गू gū
U+0918U+0942<>U+0067U+0068U+016B;घू ghū
U+0919U+0942<>U+1E45U+016B;ङू ṅū
U+091AU+0942<>U+0063U+016B;चू cū
U+091BU+0942<>U+0063U+0068U+016B;छू chū
U+091CU+0942<>U+006AU+016B;जू jū
U+091DU+0942<>U+006AU+0068U+016B;झू jhū
U+091EU+0942<>U+00F1U+016B;ञू ñū
U+091FU+0942<>U+1E6DU+016B;टू ṭū
U+0920U+0942<>U+1E6DU+0068U+016B;ठू ṭhū
U+0921U+0942<>U+1E0DU+016B;डू ḍū
U+0922U+0942<>U+1E0DU+0068U+016B;ढू ḍhū
U+0923U+0942<>U+1E47U+016B;णू ṇū
U+0924U+0942<>U+0074U+016B;तू tū
U+0925U+0942<>U+0074U+0068U+016B;थू thū
U+0926U+0942<>U+0064U+016B;दू dū
U+0927U+0942<>U+0064U+0068U+016B;धू dhū
U+0928U+0942<>U+006EU+016B;नू nū
U+092AU+0942<>U+0070U+016B;पू pū
U+092BU+0942<>U+0070U+0068U+016B;फू phū
U+092CU+0942<>U+0062U+016B;बू bū
U+092DU+0942<>U+0062U+0068U+016B;भू bhū
U+092EU+0942<>U+006DU+016B;मू mū
U+092FU+0942<>U+0079U+016B;यू yū
U+0930U+0942<>U+0072U+016B;रू rū
U+0932U+0942<>U+006CU+016B;लू lū
U+0935U+0942<>U+0076U+016B;वू vū
U+0936U+0942<>U+015BU+016B;शू śū
U+0937U+0942<>U+1E63U+016B;षू ṣū
U+0938U+0942<>U+0073U+016B;सू sū
U+0939U+0942<>U+0068U+016B;हू hū
U+0958U+0942<>U+0071U+016B;क़ू qū
U+0959U+0942<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+016B;ख़ू k͟hū
U+095AU+0942<>U+0121U+016B;ग़ू ġū
U+095BU+0942<>U+007AU+016B;ज़ू zū
U+095CU+0942<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+016B;ड़ू dddhū
U+095DU+0942<>U+1E5BU+0068U+016B;ढ़ू ṛhū
U+095EU+0942<>U+0066U+016B;फ़ू fū
U+095FU+0942<>U+0079U+0079U+016B;य़ू yyū
U+0929U+0942<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+016B;ऩू nnnū
U+0931U+0942<>U+0072U+0072U+016B;ऱू rrū
U+0933U+0942<>U+1E37U+016B;ळू ḷū
U+0934U+0942<>U+1E3BU+016B;ऴू ḻū
U+0915U+0943<>U+006BU+1E5B;कृ kṛ
U+0916U+0943<>U+006BU+0068U+1E5B;खृ khṛ
U+0917U+0943<>U+0067U+1E5B;गृ gṛ
U+0918U+0943<>U+0067U+0068U+1E5B;घृ ghṛ
U+0919U+0943<>U+1E45U+1E5B;ङृ ṅṛ
U+091AU+0943<>U+0063U+1E5B;चृ cṛ
U+091BU+0943<>U+0063U+0068U+1E5B;छृ chṛ
U+091CU+0943<>U+006AU+1E5B;जृ jṛ
U+091DU+0943<>U+006AU+0068U+1E5B;झृ jhṛ
U+091EU+0943<>U+00F1U+1E5B;ञृ ñṛ
U+091FU+0943<>U+1E6DU+1E5B;टृ ṭṛ
U+0920U+0943<>U+1E6DU+0068U+1E5B;ठृ ṭhṛ
U+0921U+0943<>U+1E0DU+1E5B;डृ ḍṛ
U+0922U+0943<>U+1E0DU+0068U+1E5B;ढृ ḍhṛ
U+0923U+0943<>U+1E47U+1E5B;णृ ṇṛ
U+0924U+0943<>U+0074U+1E5B;तृ tṛ
U+0925U+0943<>U+0074U+0068U+1E5B;थृ thṛ
U+0926U+0943<>U+0064U+1E5B;दृ dṛ
U+0927U+0943<>U+0064U+0068U+1E5B;धृ dhṛ
U+0928U+0943<>U+006EU+1E5B;नृ nṛ
U+092AU+0943<>U+0070U+1E5B;पृ pṛ
U+092BU+0943<>U+0070U+0068U+1E5B;फृ phṛ
U+092CU+0943<>U+0062U+1E5B;बृ bṛ
U+092DU+0943<>U+0062U+0068U+1E5B;भृ bhṛ
U+092EU+0943<>U+006DU+1E5B;मृ mṛ
U+092FU+0943<>U+0079U+1E5B;यृ yṛ
U+0930U+0943<>U+0072U+1E5B;रृ rṛ
U+0932U+0943<>U+006CU+1E5B;लृ lṛ
U+0935U+0943<>U+0076U+1E5B;वृ vṛ
U+0936U+0943<>U+015BU+1E5B;शृ śṛ
U+0937U+0943<>U+1E63U+1E5B;षृ ṣṛ
U+0938U+0943<>U+0073U+1E5B;सृ sṛ
U+0939U+0943<>U+0068U+1E5B;हृ hṛ
U+0958U+0943<>U+0071U+1E5B;क़ृ qṛ
U+0959U+0943<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E5B;ख़ृ k͟hṛ
U+095AU+0943<>U+0121U+1E5B;ग़ृ ġṛ
U+095BU+0943<>U+007AU+1E5B;ज़ृ zṛ
U+095CU+0943<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E5B;ड़ृ dddhṛ
U+095DU+0943<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E5B;ढ़ृ ṛhṛ
U+095EU+0943<>U+0066U+1E5B;फ़ृ fṛ
U+095FU+0943<>U+0079U+0079U+1E5B;य़ृ yyṛ
U+0929U+0943<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+1E5B;ऩृ nnnṛ
U+0931U+0943<>U+0072U+0072U+1E5B;ऱृ rrṛ
U+0933U+0943<>U+1E37U+1E5B;ळृ ḷṛ
U+0934U+0943<>U+1E3BU+1E5B;ऴृ ḻṛ
U+0915U+0944<>U+006BU+1E5D;कॄ kṝ
U+0916U+0944<>U+006BU+0068U+1E5D;खॄ khṝ
U+0917U+0944<>U+0067U+1E5D;गॄ gṝ
U+0918U+0944<>U+0067U+0068U+1E5D;घॄ ghṝ
U+0919U+0944<>U+1E45U+1E5D;ङॄ ṅṝ
U+091AU+0944<>U+0063U+1E5D;चॄ cṝ
U+091BU+0944<>U+0063U+0068U+1E5D;छॄ chṝ
U+091CU+0944<>U+006AU+1E5D;जॄ jṝ
U+091DU+0944<>U+006AU+0068U+1E5D;झॄ jhṝ
U+091EU+0944<>U+00F1U+1E5D;ञॄ ñṝ
U+091FU+0944<>U+1E6DU+1E5D;टॄ ṭṝ
U+0920U+0944<>U+1E6DU+0068U+1E5D;ठॄ ṭhṝ
U+0921U+0944<>U+1E0DU+1E5D;डॄ ḍṝ
U+0922U+0944<>U+1E0DU+0068U+1E5D;ढॄ ḍhṝ
U+0923U+0944<>U+1E47U+1E5D;णॄ ṇṝ
U+0924U+0944<>U+0074U+1E5D;तॄ tṝ
U+0925U+0944<>U+0074U+0068U+1E5D;थॄ thṝ
U+0926U+0944<>U+0064U+1E5D;दॄ dṝ
U+0927U+0944<>U+0064U+0068U+1E5D;धॄ dhṝ
U+0928U+0944<>U+006EU+1E5D;नॄ nṝ
U+092AU+0944<>U+0070U+1E5D;पॄ pṝ
U+092BU+0944<>U+0070U+0068U+1E5D;फॄ phṝ
U+092CU+0944<>U+0062U+1E5D;बॄ bṝ
U+092DU+0944<>U+0062U+0068U+1E5D;भॄ bhṝ
U+092EU+0944<>U+006DU+1E5D;मॄ mṝ
U+092FU+0944<>U+0079U+1E5D;यॄ yṝ
U+0930U+0944<>U+0072U+1E5D;रॄ rṝ
U+0932U+0944<>U+006CU+1E5D;लॄ lṝ
U+0935U+0944<>U+0076U+1E5D;वॄ vṝ
U+0936U+0944<>U+015BU+1E5D;शॄ śṝ
U+0937U+0944<>U+1E63U+1E5D;षॄ ṣṝ
U+0938U+0944<>U+0073U+1E5D;सॄ sṝ
U+0939U+0944<>U+0068U+1E5D;हॄ hṝ
U+0958U+0944<>U+0071U+1E5D;क़ॄ qṝ
U+0959U+0944<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+1E5D;ख़ॄ k͟hṝ
U+095AU+0944<>U+0121U+1E5D;ग़ॄ ġṝ
U+095BU+0944<>U+007AU+1E5D;ज़ॄ zṝ
U+095CU+0944<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+1E5D;ड़ॄ dddhṝ
U+095DU+0944<>U+1E5BU+0068U+1E5D;ढ़ॄ ṛhṝ
U+095EU+0944<>U+0066U+1E5D;फ़ॄ fṝ
U+095FU+0944<>U+0079U+0079U+1E5D;य़ॄ yyṝ
U+0929U+0944<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+1E5D;ऩॄ nnnṝ
U+0931U+0944<>U+0072U+0072U+1E5D;ऱॄ rrṝ
U+0933U+0944<>U+1E37U+1E5D;ळॄ ḷṝ
U+0934U+0944<>U+1E3BU+1E5D;ऴॄ ḻṝ
U+0915U+093E<>U+006BU+0101;का kā
U+0916U+093E<>U+006BU+0068U+0101;खा khā
U+0917U+093E<>U+0067U+0101;गा gā
U+0918U+093E<>U+0067U+0068U+0101;घा ghā
U+0919U+093E<>U+1E45U+0101;ङा ṅā
U+091AU+093E<>U+0063U+0101;चा cā
U+091BU+093E<>U+0063U+0068U+0101;छा chā
U+091CU+093E<>U+006AU+0101;जा jā
U+091DU+093E<>U+006AU+0068U+0101;झा jhā
U+091EU+093E<>U+00F1U+0101;ञा ñā
U+091FU+093E<>U+1E6DU+0101;टा ṭā
U+0920U+093E<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0101;ठा ṭhā
U+0921U+093E<>U+1E0DU+0101;डा ḍā
U+0922U+093E<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0101;ढा ḍhā
U+0923U+093E<>U+1E47U+0101;णा ṇā
U+0924U+093E<>U+0074U+0101;ता tā
U+0925U+093E<>U+0074U+0068U+0101;था thā
U+0926U+093E<>U+0064U+0101;दा dā
U+0927U+093E<>U+0064U+0068U+0101;धा dhā
U+0928U+093E<>U+006EU+0101;ना nā
U+092AU+093E<>U+0070U+0101;पा pā
U+092BU+093E<>U+0070U+0068U+0101;फा phā
U+092CU+093E<>U+0062U+0101;बा bā
U+092DU+093E<>U+0062U+0068U+0101;भा bhā
U+092EU+093E<>U+006DU+0101;मा mā
U+092FU+093E<>U+0079U+0101;या yā
U+0930U+093E<>U+0072U+0101;रा rā
U+0932U+093E<>U+006CU+0101;ला lā
U+0935U+093E<>U+0076U+0101;वा vā
U+0936U+093E<>U+015BU+0101;शा śā
U+0937U+093E<>U+1E63U+0101;षा ṣā
U+0938U+093E<>U+0073U+0101;सा sā
U+0939U+093E<>U+0068U+0101;हा hā
U+0958U+093E<>U+0071U+0101;क़ा qā
U+0959U+093E<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0101;ख़ा k͟hā
U+095AU+093E<>U+0121U+0101;ग़ा ġā
U+095BU+093E<>U+007AU+0101;ज़ा zā
U+095CU+093E<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0101;ड़ा dddhā
U+095DU+093E<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0101;ढ़ा ṛhā
U+095EU+093E<>U+0066U+0101;फ़ा fā
U+095FU+093E<>U+0079U+0079U+0101;य़ा yyā
U+0929U+093E<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0101;ऩा nnnā
U+0931U+093E<>U+0072U+0072U+0101;ऱा rrā
U+0933U+093E<>U+1E37U+0101;ळा ḷā
U+0934U+093E<>U+1E3BU+0101;ऴा ḻā
U+0915U+0947<>U+006BU+0065;के ke
U+0916U+0947<>U+006BU+0068U+0065;खे khe
U+0917U+0947<>U+0067U+0065;गे ge
U+0918U+0947<>U+0067U+0068U+0065;घे ghe
U+0919U+0947<>U+1E45U+0065;ङे ṅe
U+091AU+0947<>U+0063U+0065;चे ce
U+091BU+0947<>U+0063U+0068U+0065;छे che
U+091CU+0947<>U+006AU+0065;जे je
U+091DU+0947<>U+006AU+0068U+0065;झे jhe
U+091EU+0947<>U+00F1U+0065;ञे ñe
U+091FU+0947<>U+1E6DU+0065;टे ṭe
U+0920U+0947<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0065;ठे ṭhe
U+0921U+0947<>U+1E0DU+0065;डे ḍe
U+0922U+0947<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0065;ढे ḍhe
U+0923U+0947<>U+1E47U+0065;णे ṇe
U+0924U+0947<>U+0074U+0065;ते te
U+0925U+0947<>U+0074U+0068U+0065;थे the
U+0926U+0947<>U+0064U+0065;दे de
U+0927U+0947<>U+0064U+0068U+0065;धे dhe
U+0928U+0947<>U+006EU+0065;ने ne
U+092AU+0947<>U+0070U+0065;पे pe
U+092BU+0947<>U+0070U+0068U+0065;फे phe
U+092CU+0947<>U+0062U+0065;बे be
U+092DU+0947<>U+0062U+0068U+0065;भे bhe
U+092EU+0947<>U+006DU+0065;मे me
U+092FU+0947<>U+0079U+0065;ये ye
U+0930U+0947<>U+0072U+0065;रे re
U+0932U+0947<>U+006CU+0065;ले le
U+0935U+0947<>U+0076U+0065;वे ve
U+0936U+0947<>U+015BU+0065;शे śe
U+0937U+0947<>U+1E63U+0065;षे ṣe
U+0938U+0947<>U+0073U+0065;से se
U+0939U+0947<>U+0068U+0065;हे he
U+0958U+0947<>U+0071U+0065;क़े qe
U+0959U+0947<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065;ख़े k͟he
U+095AU+0947<>U+0121U+0065;ग़े ġe
U+095BU+0947<>U+007AU+0065;ज़े ze
U+095CU+0947<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065;ड़े dddhe
U+095DU+0947<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065;ढ़े ṛhe
U+095EU+0947<>U+0066U+0065;फ़े fe
U+095FU+0947<>U+0079U+0079U+0065;य़े yye
U+0929U+0947<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0065;ऩे nnne
U+0931U+0947<>U+0072U+0072U+0065;ऱे rre
U+0933U+0947<>U+1E37U+0065;ळे ḷe
U+0934U+0947<>U+1E3BU+0065;ऴे ḻe
U+0915U+093F<>U+006BU+0069;कि ki
U+0916U+093F<>U+006BU+0068U+0069;खि khi
U+0917U+093F<>U+0067U+0069;गि gi
U+0918U+093F<>U+0067U+0068U+0069;घि ghi
U+0919U+093F<>U+1E45U+0069;ङि ṅi
U+091AU+093F<>U+0063U+0069;चि ci
U+091BU+093F<>U+0063U+0068U+0069;छि chi
U+091CU+093F<>U+006AU+0069;जि ji
U+091DU+093F<>U+006AU+0068U+0069;झि jhi
U+091EU+093F<>U+00F1U+0069;ञि ñi
U+091FU+093F<>U+1E6DU+0069;टि ṭi
U+0920U+093F<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0069;ठि ṭhi
U+0921U+093F<>U+1E0DU+0069;डि ḍi
U+0922U+093F<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0069;ढि ḍhi
U+0923U+093F<>U+1E47U+0069;णि ṇi
U+0924U+093F<>U+0074U+0069;ति ti
U+0925U+093F<>U+0074U+0068U+0069;थि thi
U+0926U+093F<>U+0064U+0069;दि di
U+0927U+093F<>U+0064U+0068U+0069;धि dhi
U+0928U+093F<>U+006EU+0069;नि ni
U+092AU+093F<>U+0070U+0069;पि pi
U+092BU+093F<>U+0070U+0068U+0069;फि phi
U+092CU+093F<>U+0062U+0069;बि bi
U+092DU+093F<>U+0062U+0068U+0069;भि bhi
U+092EU+093F<>U+006DU+0069;मि mi
U+092FU+093F<>U+0079U+0069;यि yi
U+0930U+093F<>U+0072U+0069;रि ri
U+0932U+093F<>U+006CU+0069;लि li
U+0935U+093F<>U+0076U+0069;वि vi
U+0936U+093F<>U+015BU+0069;शि śi
U+0937U+093F<>U+1E63U+0069;षि ṣi
U+0938U+093F<>U+0073U+0069;सि si
U+0939U+093F<>U+0068U+0069;हि hi
U+0958U+093F<>U+0071U+0069;क़ि qi
U+0959U+093F<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0069;ख़ि k͟hi
U+095AU+093F<>U+0121U+0069;ग़ि ġi
U+095BU+093F<>U+007AU+0069;ज़ि zi
U+095CU+093F<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0069;ड़ि dddhi
U+095DU+093F<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0069;ढ़ि ṛhi
U+095EU+093F<>U+0066U+0069;फ़ि fi
U+095FU+093F<>U+0079U+0079U+0069;य़ि yyi
U+0929U+093F<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0069;ऩि nnni
U+0931U+093F<>U+0072U+0072U+0069;ऱि rri
U+0933U+093F<>U+1E37U+0069;ळि ḷi
U+0934U+093F<>U+1E3BU+0069;ऴि ḻi
U+0915U+0940<>U+006BU+012B;की kī
U+0916U+0940<>U+006BU+0068U+012B;खी khī
U+0917U+0940<>U+0067U+012B;गी gī
U+0918U+0940<>U+0067U+0068U+012B;घी ghī
U+0919U+0940<>U+1E45U+012B;ङी ṅī
U+091AU+0940<>U+0063U+012B;ची cī
U+091BU+0940<>U+0063U+0068U+012B;छी chī
U+091CU+0940<>U+006AU+012B;जी jī
U+091DU+0940<>U+006AU+0068U+012B;झी jhī
U+091EU+0940<>U+00F1U+012B;ञी ñī
U+091FU+0940<>U+1E6DU+012B;टी ṭī
U+0920U+0940<>U+1E6DU+0068U+012B;ठी ṭhī
U+0921U+0940<>U+1E0DU+012B;डी ḍī
U+0922U+0940<>U+1E0DU+0068U+012B;ढी ḍhī
U+0923U+0940<>U+1E47U+012B;णी ṇī
U+0924U+0940<>U+0074U+012B;ती tī
U+0925U+0940<>U+0074U+0068U+012B;थी thī
U+0926U+0940<>U+0064U+012B;दी dī
U+0927U+0940<>U+0064U+0068U+012B;धी dhī
U+0928U+0940<>U+006EU+012B;नी nī
U+092AU+0940<>U+0070U+012B;पी pī
U+092BU+0940<>U+0070U+0068U+012B;फी phī
U+092CU+0940<>U+0062U+012B;बी bī
U+092DU+0940<>U+0062U+0068U+012B;भी bhī
U+092EU+0940<>U+006DU+012B;मी mī
U+092FU+0940<>U+0079U+012B;यी yī
U+0930U+0940<>U+0072U+012B;री rī
U+0932U+0940<>U+006CU+012B;ली lī
U+0935U+0940<>U+0076U+012B;वी vī
U+0936U+0940<>U+015BU+012B;शी śī
U+0937U+0940<>U+1E63U+012B;षी ṣī
U+0938U+0940<>U+0073U+012B;सी sī
U+0939U+0940<>U+0068U+012B;ही hī
U+0958U+0940<>U+0071U+012B;क़ी qī
U+0959U+0940<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+012B;ख़ी k͟hī
U+095AU+0940<>U+0121U+012B;ग़ी ġī
U+095BU+0940<>U+007AU+012B;ज़ी zī
U+095CU+0940<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+012B;ड़ी dddhī
U+095DU+0940<>U+1E5BU+0068U+012B;ढ़ी ṛhī
U+095EU+0940<>U+0066U+012B;फ़ी fī
U+095FU+0940<>U+0079U+0079U+012B;य़ी yyī
U+0929U+0940<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+012B;ऩी nnnī
U+0931U+0940<>U+0072U+0072U+012B;ऱी rrī
U+0933U+0940<>U+1E37U+012B;ळी ḷī
U+0934U+0940<>U+1E3BU+012B;ऴी ḻī
U+0915U+094B<>U+006BU+006F;को ko
U+0916U+094B<>U+006BU+0068U+006F;खो kho
U+0917U+094B<>U+0067U+006F;गो go
U+0918U+094B<>U+0067U+0068U+006F;घो gho
U+0919U+094B<>U+1E45U+006F;ङो ṅo
U+091AU+094B<>U+0063U+006F;चो co
U+091BU+094B<>U+0063U+0068U+006F;छो cho
U+091CU+094B<>U+006AU+006F;जो jo
U+091DU+094B<>U+006AU+0068U+006F;झो jho
U+091EU+094B<>U+00F1U+006F;ञो ño
U+091FU+094B<>U+1E6DU+006F;टो ṭo
U+0920U+094B<>U+1E6DU+0068U+006F;ठो ṭho
U+0921U+094B<>U+1E0DU+006F;डो ḍo
U+0922U+094B<>U+1E0DU+0068U+006F;ढो ḍho
U+0923U+094B<>U+1E47U+006F;णो ṇo
U+0924U+094B<>U+0074U+006F;तो to
U+0925U+094B<>U+0074U+0068U+006F;थो tho
U+0926U+094B<>U+0064U+006F;दो do
U+0927U+094B<>U+0064U+0068U+006F;धो dho
U+0928U+094B<>U+006EU+006F;नो no
U+092AU+094B<>U+0070U+006F;पो po
U+092BU+094B<>U+0070U+0068U+006F;फो pho
U+092CU+094B<>U+0062U+006F;बो bo
U+092DU+094B<>U+0062U+0068U+006F;भो bho
U+092EU+094B<>U+006DU+006F;मो mo
U+092FU+094B<>U+0079U+006F;यो yo
U+0930U+094B<>U+0072U+006F;रो ro
U+0932U+094B<>U+006CU+006F;लो lo
U+0935U+094B<>U+0076U+006F;वो vo
U+0936U+094B<>U+015BU+006F;शो śo
U+0937U+094B<>U+1E63U+006F;षो ṣo
U+0938U+094B<>U+0073U+006F;सो so
U+0939U+094B<>U+0068U+006F;हो ho
U+0958U+094B<>U+0071U+006F;क़ो qo
U+0959U+094B<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006F;ख़ो k͟ho
U+095AU+094B<>U+0121U+006F;ग़ो ġo
U+095BU+094B<>U+007AU+006F;ज़ो zo
U+095CU+094B<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006F;ड़ो dddho
U+095DU+094B<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006F;ढ़ो ṛho
U+095EU+094B<>U+0066U+006F;फ़ो fo
U+095FU+094B<>U+0079U+0079U+006F;य़ो yyo
U+0929U+094B<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+006F;ऩो nnno
U+0931U+094B<>U+0072U+0072U+006F;ऱो rro
U+0933U+094B<>U+1E37U+006F;ळो ḷo
U+0934U+094B<>U+1E3BU+006F;ऴो ḻo
U+0915U+0948<>U+006BU+0061U+0069;कै kai
U+0916U+0948<>U+006BU+0068U+0061U+0069;खै khai
U+0917U+0948<>U+0067U+0061U+0069;गै gai
U+0918U+0948<>U+0067U+0068U+0061U+0069;घै ghai
U+0919U+0948<>U+1E45U+0061U+0069;ङै ṅai
U+091AU+0948<>U+0063U+0061U+0069;चै cai
U+091BU+0948<>U+0063U+0068U+0061U+0069;छै chai
U+091CU+0948<>U+006AU+0061U+0069;जै jai
U+091DU+0948<>U+006AU+0068U+0061U+0069;झै jhai
U+091EU+0948<>U+00F1U+0061U+0069;ञै ñai
U+091FU+0948<>U+1E6DU+0061U+0069;टै ṭai
U+0920U+0948<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0061U+0069;ठै ṭhai
U+0921U+0948<>U+1E0DU+0061U+0069;डै ḍai
U+0922U+0948<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0061U+0069;ढै ḍhai
U+0923U+0948<>U+1E47U+0061U+0069;णै ṇai
U+0924U+0948<>U+0074U+0061U+0069;तै tai
U+0925U+0948<>U+0074U+0068U+0061U+0069;थै thai
U+0926U+0948<>U+0064U+0061U+0069;दै dai
U+0927U+0948<>U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0069;धै dhai
U+0928U+0948<>U+006EU+0061U+0069;नै nai
U+092AU+0948<>U+0070U+0061U+0069;पै pai
U+092BU+0948<>U+0070U+0068U+0061U+0069;फै phai
U+092CU+0948<>U+0062U+0061U+0069;बै bai
U+092DU+0948<>U+0062U+0068U+0061U+0069;भै bhai
U+092EU+0948<>U+006DU+0061U+0069;मै mai
U+092FU+0948<>U+0079U+0061U+0069;यै yai
U+0930U+0948<>U+0072U+0061U+0069;रै rai
U+0932U+0948<>U+006CU+0061U+0069;लै lai
U+0935U+0948<>U+0076U+0061U+0069;वै vai
U+0936U+0948<>U+015BU+0061U+0069;शै śai
U+0937U+0948<>U+1E63U+0061U+0069;षै ṣai
U+0938U+0948<>U+0073U+0061U+0069;सै sai
U+0939U+0948<>U+0068U+0061U+0069;है hai
U+0958U+0948<>U+0071U+0061U+0069;क़ै qai
U+0959U+0948<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0061U+0069;ख़ै k͟hai
U+095AU+0948<>U+0121U+0061U+0069;ग़ै ġai
U+095BU+0948<>U+007AU+0061U+0069;ज़ै zai
U+095CU+0948<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0061U+0069;ड़ै dddhai
U+095DU+0948<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0061U+0069;ढ़ै ṛhai
U+095EU+0948<>U+0066U+0061U+0069;फ़ै fai
U+095FU+0948<>U+0079U+0079U+0061U+0069;य़ै yyai
U+0929U+0948<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0061U+0069;ऩै nnnai
U+0931U+0948<>U+0072U+0072U+0061U+0069;ऱै rrai
U+0933U+0948<>U+1E37U+0061U+0069;ळै ḷai
U+0934U+0948<>U+1E3BU+0061U+0069;ऴै ḻai
U+0915U+093A<>U+006BU+006FU+0065;कऺ koe
U+0916U+093A<>U+006BU+0068U+006FU+0065;खऺ khoe
U+0917U+093A<>U+0067U+006FU+0065;गऺ goe
U+0918U+093A<>U+0067U+0068U+006FU+0065;घऺ ghoe
U+0919U+093A<>U+1E45U+006FU+0065;ङऺ ṅoe
U+091AU+093A<>U+0063U+006FU+0065;चऺ coe
U+091BU+093A<>U+0063U+0068U+006FU+0065;छऺ choe
U+091CU+093A<>U+006AU+006FU+0065;जऺ joe
U+091DU+093A<>U+006AU+0068U+006FU+0065;झऺ jhoe
U+091EU+093A<>U+00F1U+006FU+0065;ञऺ ñoe
U+091FU+093A<>U+1E6DU+006FU+0065;टऺ ṭoe
U+0920U+093A<>U+1E6DU+0068U+006FU+0065;ठऺ ṭhoe
U+0921U+093A<>U+1E0DU+006FU+0065;डऺ ḍoe
U+0922U+093A<>U+1E0DU+0068U+006FU+0065;ढऺ ḍhoe
U+0923U+093A<>U+1E47U+006FU+0065;णऺ ṇoe
U+0924U+093A<>U+0074U+006FU+0065;तऺ toe
U+0925U+093A<>U+0074U+0068U+006FU+0065;थऺ thoe
U+0926U+093A<>U+0064U+006FU+0065;दऺ doe
U+0927U+093A<>U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0065;धऺ dhoe
U+0928U+093A<>U+006EU+006FU+0065;नऺ noe
U+092AU+093A<>U+0070U+006FU+0065;पऺ poe
U+092BU+093A<>U+0070U+0068U+006FU+0065;फऺ phoe
U+092CU+093A<>U+0062U+006FU+0065;बऺ boe
U+092DU+093A<>U+0062U+0068U+006FU+0065;भऺ bhoe
U+092EU+093A<>U+006DU+006FU+0065;मऺ moe
U+092FU+093A<>U+0079U+006FU+0065;यऺ yoe
U+0930U+093A<>U+0072U+006FU+0065;रऺ roe
U+0932U+093A<>U+006CU+006FU+0065;लऺ loe
U+0935U+093A<>U+0076U+006FU+0065;वऺ voe
U+0936U+093A<>U+015BU+006FU+0065;शऺ śoe
U+0937U+093A<>U+1E63U+006FU+0065;षऺ ṣoe
U+0938U+093A<>U+0073U+006FU+0065;सऺ soe
U+0939U+093A<>U+0068U+006FU+0065;हऺ hoe
U+0958U+093A<>U+0071U+006FU+0065;क़ऺ qoe
U+0959U+093A<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006FU+0065;ख़ऺ k͟hoe
U+095AU+093A<>U+0121U+006FU+0065;ग़ऺ ġoe
U+095BU+093A<>U+007AU+006FU+0065;ज़ऺ zoe
U+095CU+093A<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0065;ड़ऺ dddhoe
U+095DU+093A<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006FU+0065;ढ़ऺ ṛhoe
U+095EU+093A<>U+0066U+006FU+0065;फ़ऺ foe
U+095FU+093A<>U+0079U+0079U+006FU+0065;य़ऺ yyoe
U+0929U+093A<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+006FU+0065;ऩऺ nnnoe
U+0931U+093A<>U+0072U+0072U+006FU+0065;ऱऺ rroe
U+0933U+093A<>U+1E37U+006FU+0065;ळऺ ḷoe
U+0934U+093A<>U+1E3BU+006FU+0065;ऴऺ ḻoe
U+0915U+093B<>U+006BU+014DU+0065;कऻ kōe
U+0916U+093B<>U+006BU+0068U+014DU+0065;खऻ khōe
U+0917U+093B<>U+0067U+014DU+0065;गऻ gōe
U+0918U+093B<>U+0067U+0068U+014DU+0065;घऻ ghōe
U+0919U+093B<>U+1E45U+014DU+0065;ङऻ ṅōe
U+091AU+093B<>U+0063U+014DU+0065;चऻ cōe
U+091BU+093B<>U+0063U+0068U+014DU+0065;छऻ chōe
U+091CU+093B<>U+006AU+014DU+0065;जऻ jōe
U+091DU+093B<>U+006AU+0068U+014DU+0065;झऻ jhōe
U+091EU+093B<>U+00F1U+014DU+0065;ञऻ ñōe
U+091FU+093B<>U+1E6DU+014DU+0065;टऻ ṭōe
U+0920U+093B<>U+1E6DU+0068U+014DU+0065;ठऻ ṭhōe
U+0921U+093B<>U+1E0DU+014DU+0065;डऻ ḍōe
U+0922U+093B<>U+1E0DU+0068U+014DU+0065;ढऻ ḍhōe
U+0923U+093B<>U+1E47U+014DU+0065;णऻ ṇōe
U+0924U+093B<>U+0074U+014DU+0065;तऻ tōe
U+0925U+093B<>U+0074U+0068U+014DU+0065;थऻ thōe
U+0926U+093B<>U+0064U+014DU+0065;दऻ dōe
U+0927U+093B<>U+0064U+0068U+014DU+0065;धऻ dhōe
U+0928U+093B<>U+006EU+014DU+0065;नऻ nōe
U+092AU+093B<>U+0070U+014DU+0065;पऻ pōe
U+092BU+093B<>U+0070U+0068U+014DU+0065;फऻ phōe
U+092CU+093B<>U+0062U+014DU+0065;बऻ bōe
U+092DU+093B<>U+0062U+0068U+014DU+0065;भऻ bhōe
U+092EU+093B<>U+006DU+014DU+0065;मऻ mōe
U+092FU+093B<>U+0079U+014DU+0065;यऻ yōe
U+0930U+093B<>U+0072U+014DU+0065;रऻ rōe
U+0932U+093B<>U+006CU+014DU+0065;लऻ lōe
U+0935U+093B<>U+0076U+014DU+0065;वऻ vōe
U+0936U+093B<>U+015BU+014DU+0065;शऻ śōe
U+0937U+093B<>U+1E63U+014DU+0065;षऻ ṣōe
U+0938U+093B<>U+0073U+014DU+0065;सऻ sōe
U+0939U+093B<>U+0068U+014DU+0065;हऻ hōe
U+0958U+093B<>U+0071U+014DU+0065;क़ऻ qōe
U+0959U+093B<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+014DU+0065;ख़ऻ k͟hōe
U+095AU+093B<>U+0121U+014DU+0065;ग़ऻ ġōe
U+095BU+093B<>U+007AU+014DU+0065;ज़ऻ zōe
U+095CU+093B<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+014DU+0065;ड़ऻ dddhōe
U+095DU+093B<>U+1E5BU+0068U+014DU+0065;ढ़ऻ ṛhōe
U+095EU+093B<>U+0066U+014DU+0065;फ़ऻ fōe
U+095FU+093B<>U+0079U+0079U+014DU+0065;य़ऻ yyōe
U+0929U+093B<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+014DU+0065;ऩऻ nnnōe
U+0931U+093B<>U+0072U+0072U+014DU+0065;ऱऻ rrōe
U+0933U+093B<>U+1E37U+014DU+0065;ळऻ ḷōe
U+0934U+093B<>U+1E3BU+014DU+0065;ऴऻ ḻōe
U+0915U+0946<>U+006BU+0065U+0306;कॆ kĕ
U+0916U+0946<>U+006BU+0068U+0065U+0306;खॆ khĕ
U+0917U+0946<>U+0067U+0065U+0306;गॆ gĕ
U+0918U+0946<>U+0067U+0068U+0065U+0306;घॆ ghĕ
U+0919U+0946<>U+1E45U+0065U+0306;ङॆ ṅĕ
U+091AU+0946<>U+0063U+0065U+0306;चॆ cĕ
U+091BU+0946<>U+0063U+0068U+0065U+0306;छॆ chĕ
U+091CU+0946<>U+006AU+0065U+0306;जॆ jĕ
U+091DU+0946<>U+006AU+0068U+0065U+0306;झॆ jhĕ
U+091EU+0946<>U+00F1U+0065U+0306;ञॆ ñĕ
U+091FU+0946<>U+1E6DU+0065U+0306;टॆ ṭĕ
U+0920U+0946<>U+1E6DU+0068U+0065U+0306;ठॆ ṭhĕ
U+0921U+0946<>U+1E0DU+0065U+0306;डॆ ḍĕ
U+0922U+0946<>U+1E0DU+0068U+0065U+0306;ढॆ ḍhĕ
U+0923U+0946<>U+1E47U+0065U+0306;णॆ ṇĕ
U+0924U+0946<>U+0074U+0065U+0306;तॆ tĕ
U+0925U+0946<>U+0074U+0068U+0065U+0306;थॆ thĕ
U+0926U+0946<>U+0064U+0065U+0306;दॆ dĕ
U+0927U+0946<>U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0306;धॆ dhĕ
U+0928U+0946<>U+006EU+0065U+0306;नॆ nĕ
U+092AU+0946<>U+0070U+0065U+0306;पॆ pĕ
U+092BU+0946<>U+0070U+0068U+0065U+0306;फॆ phĕ
U+092CU+0946<>U+0062U+0065U+0306;बॆ bĕ
U+092DU+0946<>U+0062U+0068U+0065U+0306;भॆ bhĕ
U+092EU+0946<>U+006DU+0065U+0306;मॆ mĕ
U+092FU+0946<>U+0079U+0065U+0306;यॆ yĕ
U+0930U+0946<>U+0072U+0065U+0306;रॆ rĕ
U+0932U+0946<>U+006CU+0065U+0306;लॆ lĕ
U+0935U+0946<>U+0076U+0065U+0306;वॆ vĕ
U+0936U+0946<>U+015BU+0065U+0306;शॆ śĕ
U+0937U+0946<>U+1E63U+0065U+0306;षॆ ṣĕ
U+0938U+0946<>U+0073U+0065U+0306;सॆ sĕ
U+0939U+0946<>U+0068U+0065U+0306;हॆ hĕ
U+0958U+0946<>U+0071U+0065U+0306;क़ॆ qĕ
U+0959U+0946<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+0065U+0306;ख़ॆ k͟hĕ
U+095AU+0946<>U+0121U+0065U+0306;ग़ॆ ġĕ
U+095BU+0946<>U+007AU+0065U+0306;ज़ॆ zĕ
U+095CU+0946<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+0065U+0306;ड़ॆ dddhĕ
U+095DU+0946<>U+1E5BU+0068U+0065U+0306;ढ़ॆ ṛhĕ
U+095EU+0946<>U+0066U+0065U+0306;फ़ॆ fĕ
U+095FU+0946<>U+0079U+0079U+0065U+0306;य़ॆ yyĕ
U+0929U+0946<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+0065U+0306;ऩॆ nnnĕ
U+0931U+0946<>U+0072U+0072U+0065U+0306;ऱॆ rrĕ
U+0933U+0946<>U+1E37U+0065U+0306;ळॆ ḷĕ
U+0934U+0946<>U+1E3BU+0065U+0306;ऴॆ ḻĕ
U+0915U+094A<>U+006BU+006FU+0306;कॊ kŏ
U+0916U+094A<>U+006BU+0068U+006FU+0306;खॊ khŏ
U+0917U+094A<>U+0067U+006FU+0306;गॊ gŏ
U+0918U+094A<>U+0067U+0068U+006FU+0306;घॊ ghŏ
U+0919U+094A<>U+1E45U+006FU+0306;ङॊ ṅŏ
U+091AU+094A<>U+0063U+006FU+0306;चॊ cŏ
U+091BU+094A<>U+0063U+0068U+006FU+0306;छॊ chŏ
U+091CU+094A<>U+006AU+006FU+0306;जॊ jŏ
U+091DU+094A<>U+006AU+0068U+006FU+0306;झॊ jhŏ
U+091EU+094A<>U+00F1U+006FU+0306;ञॊ ñŏ
U+091FU+094A<>U+1E6DU+006FU+0306;टॊ ṭŏ
U+0920U+094A<>U+1E6DU+0068U+006FU+0306;ठॊ ṭhŏ
U+0921U+094A<>U+1E0DU+006FU+0306;डॊ ḍŏ
U+0922U+094A<>U+1E0DU+0068U+006FU+0306;ढॊ ḍhŏ
U+0923U+094A<>U+1E47U+006FU+0306;णॊ ṇŏ
U+0924U+094A<>U+0074U+006FU+0306;तॊ tŏ
U+0925U+094A<>U+0074U+0068U+006FU+0306;थॊ thŏ
U+0926U+094A<>U+0064U+006FU+0306;दॊ dŏ
U+0927U+094A<>U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0306;धॊ dhŏ
U+0928U+094A<>U+006EU+006FU+0306;नॊ nŏ
U+092AU+094A<>U+0070U+006FU+0306;पॊ pŏ
U+092BU+094A<>U+0070U+0068U+006FU+0306;फॊ phŏ
U+092CU+094A<>U+0062U+006FU+0306;बॊ bŏ
U+092DU+094A<>U+0062U+0068U+006FU+0306;भॊ bhŏ
U+092EU+094A<>U+006DU+006FU+0306;मॊ mŏ
U+092FU+094A<>U+0079U+006FU+0306;यॊ yŏ
U+0930U+094A<>U+0072U+006FU+0306;रॊ rŏ
U+0932U+094A<>U+006CU+006FU+0306;लॊ lŏ
U+0935U+094A<>U+0076U+006FU+0306;वॊ vŏ
U+0936U+094A<>U+015BU+006FU+0306;शॊ śŏ
U+0937U+094A<>U+1E63U+006FU+0306;षॊ ṣŏ
U+0938U+094A<>U+0073U+006FU+0306;सॊ sŏ
U+0939U+094A<>U+0068U+006FU+0306;हॊ hŏ
U+0958U+094A<>U+0071U+006FU+0306;क़ॊ qŏ
U+0959U+094A<>U+006BU+035FU+0068U+006FU+0306;ख़ॊ k͟hŏ
U+095AU+094A<>U+0121U+006FU+0306;ग़ॊ ġŏ
U+095BU+094A<>U+007AU+006FU+0306;ज़ॊ zŏ
U+095CU+094A<>U+0064U+0064U+0064U+0068U+006FU+0306;ड़ॊ dddhŏ
U+095DU+094A<>U+1E5BU+0068U+006FU+0306;ढ़ॊ ṛhŏ
U+095EU+094A<>U+0066U+006FU+0306;फ़ॊ fŏ
U+095FU+094A<>U+0079U+0079U+006FU+0306;य़ॊ yyŏ
U+0929U+094A<>U+006EU+006EU+006EU+006FU+0306;ऩॊ nnnŏ
U+0931U+094A<>U+0072U+0072U+006FU+0306;ऱॊ rrŏ
U+0933U+094A<>U+1E37U+006FU+0306;ळॊ ḷŏ
U+0934U+094A<>U+1E3BU+006FU+0306;ऴॊ ḻŏ
```